# Can reputation from SU and SF be counted on meta?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I understand segregating reputation on the different sites, but since meta.SO is being used for discussion of SU and SF as well, it seems prudent for reputation earned on those sites to apply to meta.SO.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451

Comment: This sounds strangely famililar to real life. Just because you can program and type well does not mean you can communicate well with others about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rep on any of the sites will not be a good indicator of your ability to discuss the sites themselves. It is entirely possible to get a high rep on a site and still not have any real understanding of the mechanics or the social dynamics that make the sites the beasts they are.

Comment: Typing on phone sucks

Comment: Thanks.  I actually was under the (clearly false) impression that reputation on SO (but not SU or SF) carried over to meta.  The system certainly makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm tempted to agree with you, I think there may be more value in the system as is. High rep users on meta are (at least in theory) people who have provided helpful answers and participated meaninfully in discussions. As such, they are probably the best people to have the powers that come with high rep.

Answer (score 1):

Makes more sense to me that if someone wants to bring rep on the other sites into consideration on Meta that they can just view that person's profile and click the Accounts tab to see the rep on the other sites.  I don't think it *necessarily* follows that someone who can answer "how do I do this in C#", or "what's wrong with my freaking server" would also have the right gauge on how the sites should work.