# My rep on meta.SO doesn't match that on SO

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, reputation, meta

Is this by-design or a bug?

Comment: +1 if only for a good question, but I have the feeling it's going to get asked again ... and again ... and again ... and ... and ... .. .. ..

Comment: Careful, or your rep on SO will soon match your rep on meta SO ... they have an odd sense of humor.

Comment: @drachenstern It's already been asked again and again and again

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should reputation from SO carry over to Meta?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta)

Comment: @Michael ~ I felt there was some difference in the two. One seemed to be someone who knew the system, one didn't, or at least, that was my casual perusal...

Comment: @drachenstern Sure, but it's pretty common to close "is this a bug?" questions as duplicates of questions that explain them. There was a better duplicate, but it's deleted for some reason: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58695/why-is-meta-stack-overflow-rep-different-from-stack-overflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's by design.

Meta.SO does not work like the other metas, it's independent

Comment: I see. In that case it's rather confusing. Would be clearer if the current **meta.SO** was **meta.SE**, and the current **meta.SE** was.... whatever.

Comment: @Tshepang This has often been brought up, but the problem is that "whatever" deal.

Comment: @Tshe, yeah.  This is essentially meta.SE-2.0.  We can't change the name to meta.SE because the old meta.SE is for SE-1.0 sites.  This meta server both StackOverflow and the SE engine in general.

Comment: @jjn Wow! It's even worse than I thought! I wasn't aware that __meta.SE__ was for SE-1.0 sites!

Comment: @Tshe, yeah.  If it weren't for that, I'd bet this site would have been renamed already.

Answer (score 3):

Because being good at writing funny questions and witty remarks doesn't necessarily make you useful at answering programming questions.