# Why is Super User's meta reputation not separate from the main site like Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should reputation from SO carry over to Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta)

I've noticed that the Stack Overflow meta has its own reputation but on Super User meta it's derived from parent site. Why is not same procedure is following there for reputation of its own meta itself?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83313/why-are-high-rep-so-users-denied-permissions-to-participate-in-meta, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/should-reputation-from-so-carry-over-to-meta

Comment: Also related:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71926/my-rep-on-meta-so-doesnt-match-that-on-so

Answer (score 3):

It's Meta.Stackoverflow which is special; every other StackExchange site shares rep with its Meta site.

Comment: Why other meta ain't special only this one is?

Comment: @avirk because this meta isn't really just for stuff related to SO, it's for the whole Stack Exchange network

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't it be called "Meta Stack Exchange"?

Comment: @Chris There's some confusion because there was a Meta Stack Exchange, but it was only for SE 1.0 sites. http://meta.stackexchange.com/ does point here now, but the name hasn't changed