# Spelling and Grammar Flag?

Tags: feature-request, questions, etiquette

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-users-edit-other-users-posts-to-correct-grammar-and-spelling-problems) question touched on it briefly but how should the spelling and grammar be handled by users who do not have enough rep to edit posts.

I often come across posts where the spelling and grammar makes the question illegible, and it will take a significant amount of time in my case to gain the rep required to edit these posts.

We can flag posts for everything except potential grammar, and filling each question with comments advising the OP to fix his grammar or spelling, doesn't make sense.

Suggestions, Comments, Potential Flag for Grammar/Spelling option?

Comment: First of all, let's fix the spelling of "grammar"... ;)

Comment: If I had enough rep, I'd edit and correct the spelling...

Comment: Spelling fixed, but I haven't tried to rework the sentences themselves.

Comment: Thanks - My point made. Now where did I put that spell check plugin :)

Comment: too niche - hopefully most people who have the ability to see a problem and edit the tags should be able to just fix the problem

Comment: Yah I try to edit what I can, but the "text talk" written questions kind of "grind my gears". haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just [use the moderator flag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/raising-a-red-flag/) for this -- there's a place where you enter the reason.

[image]

Comment: Are you setting the moderators up to be "clippy", then?

Comment: IT LOOKS LIKE YOU'RE WRITING A QUESTION!

Comment: Fair enough, and point taken. However it would save a few keystrokes and spelling mistakes in the reason. Also not entirely sure if just the moderators should be doing this?

Comment: Jeff- I'm surprised to see you provided this answer.  Do you really want to be nagged by users about every spelling error on the site?

Comment: Why make a moderator fix someone's spelling errors?  Can't the OP be bothered to fix them?  A flag from the community, to the OP, would be very nice.

Answer (score 5):

It could be a "Requires cleanup" flag that people over a certain rep can see.

There is a catch though. If you put that required rep at 2000 (edit post rep). And let's say 5% of the 2000> people look at that queue. Even at that number we have way way to many people looking at one post that possibly has a few spelling errors.

Comment: I also think a tag is a good idea, problem is again if you don't have the rep to retag. The big issue is the lack of rep here :)

Answer (score 5):

What if the rep-challenged were able to submit a possible edit to the question, and someone with more reputation were able to approve or reject the change (somewhat like flagged revisions in Wikipedia)?

**Update:** Suggested edits are now part of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind this idea. Especially if there was a nice separate list with an RSS feed.

Perhaps just an RSS feed even?

At least then as an editor I could be working on things I knew were bothering the community. It is difficult to be everywhere all the time, so this could certainly help to give me and other editors more 'eyes'.