# Self destructing comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Most of the time (but not always) when I post a comment it is only relevant for a short time - a day or two.

For example a comment might say `"Please post some code."` A reply might be `"Thanks, I've added code to the question."`  From this point on, both comments are nothing more than a distraction from the question itself, and from any more helpful comments which appear under the question.  If my comment received a few votes, it will appear in the short list of comments and possibly drown more valuable content.

If I'm diligent, I might come back and delete my comment, but then we have a hole in the conversation which can be even more of a distraction. Ultimately eventually the responder should come back and delete their response, but this is unlikely to happen if the responder is a passer-by and has no ongoing interest in the question.

The votes on answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8780/comment-conventions) indicate that the community preference is to delete your own comments when they become irrelevant, but in practice I don't think this happens often, and when it does, it can break comment continuity.

I'd love to see a mechanism whereby I could post a comment, and it would be deleted after a day or two. Users replying to the comment could use the same mechanism.

Comment: You want *your* comment to dictate the lifetime of *other* comments?  No thanks.

Comment: @Aarobot - fair enough, on rethinking it that doesn't make sense - I've edited the last para.  But now your comment doesn't make any sense, and if you delete it, this comment won't make any sense!