# Condense comments until clicked on

Tags: feature-request, comments

When the comments are listed to either a question or answer, sometimes there are rather long comments, pushing the length limits. Other times there are loads upon loads of comments. I know there's settings to only show a few, and then click to load the rest. But I consider that a crutch when I think about my idea.

This is just like when you're browsing any list of posts which show the first little bit, only enough to fill 2 lines of text. When comments are listed, if it's more than 2-3 lines for example, cut it down. This way, you can do a bit less scrolling on those posts that have a lot of long comments. Because after expanding all the comments of some of these posts, it takes sometimes 20 mouse wheel turns to get past all the comments. (Well, not for me, more like "wireless mouse touch-sensitive scroll" or whatever they call it).

Obviously there would have to be some sort of indication on each comment if it has been shortened. To the right, there should be a "..." at the end of the text, as well as some sort of indicator such as an arrow pointing down. When clicking on that comment (or tapping your finger), it expands to the full text. If you click again after it's expanded, it will condense it again.

A very similar method is at play on [Google News](http://news.google.com/). When you're browsing news headlines, if you click on one, it expands and shows more info and related stories. Click on it again, and it shrinks back to its small box. This is exactly how I imagine the comments to work on Stack Overflow, and why not all Stack Exchange sites?

PS - I originally thought that 2 lines of text would do the trick, but now I'm debating with myself whether it should be 1 or 2 lines. I figured I'd leave that decision up for higher authority.

---

**UPDATE**

Yeah, I'm thinking 2-3 line limits would be more adequate.

Comment: Okay okay obviously people don't like this idea, but does it really call for so many downvotes?

Comment: if you propose a feature request, and people disagree that it should be implemented (or at least that it should be implemented the way you suggest), down-voting is one way they can express that disagreement. If you aren't willing to accept that consequence...

Comment: Yes, but even 1 or 2 is more than enough to show it's not wanted

Comment: your argument makes no sense. Why shouldn't anyone be able to weigh in now, when they don't know who's going to vote in which way later? If someone scores a touchdown in a football game, do you just call the game right there?

Comment: My argument is more-so I assumed people would have liked the idea

Comment: 20 mouse wheel turns? Two scrolls on my scroll wheel takes me to the bottom of this page. Normally, in less than one I can get past all but the longest comment threads (which normally only exist on meta anyway). How low is your scroll wheel speed set!?

Comment: Depends where you're at I mean, I've seen questions and answers with over 100 comments. I searched for some examples but couldn't find any.

Comment: You have a scroll bar, page up/down and the middle-click scrolling doodad in addition to the scroll wheel for such rare circumstances. I suggest you use them!

Comment: ...Unless on a touch screen such as an iPad

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically hide old comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182295/automatically-hide-old-comments). See also: [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Personally, I would find it incredibly annoying to have to individually click on each comment to expand out the entire thing when I'd like to quickly get caught up on a post. I find the current method of highlighting "popular" comments after a certain number to be quite effective, as even without loading all of them you can generally get a feel for what the conversation is about.

I feel that implementing this would possibly help a small percentage of questions, but hurt the majority. It's likely that if a question, between it and the answers, were to draw the number of comments to require a laborous amount of scrolling, the question was possibly poorly phrased in the first place. If it was clarified after the fact, then the comments probably aren't needed any further, and would be candidates for deletion.

Comment: +1 Very true. But let's look at the average line count of the average comments. It's usually 1-2 lines. Maybe increase it to 3?

Comment: Actually, I'd love for a moderator to give us that calculation...

Comment: Maybe an alternative suggestion you could throw out would be an option to truncate long comments. Wouldn't affect people like me who like to see the whole thing, but would help people like you who prefer not to.