# My question has been deleted, hasn't it?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question on SO. It has been closed/opened/closed. But I'm not complaining about that.

I was just looking for it on my profile, there were some content and people arguing in comments if it should be stay opened or closed.

Anyway I was looking for it to add some content to the question, the problem is I can't find that question. Has it been deleted? the hard way? Why can't I see it, even if I'm the author?

I thought *deleted* content is not really deleted but *hidden* for low-rep users. Do I have to have an higher rep to see my own deleted content? Do you keep that information on the database  bump?

Comment: Do you have a link? Now I'm curious about it.

Comment: (Check your browser history if you have no other way of accessing it.)

Comment: How long ago did you ask this question? I'm not seeing any likely candidates on the deleted questions list.

Comment: new question? old question? possible title/topic?

Comment: @Jeff: Wait, can't moderators see deleted questions in user profiles?

Comment: I went through the recently deleted stuff, did not find it there.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking on ServerFault or SuperUser for it, in case it was migrated instead of being deleted.

Comment: But wouldn't it still appear in the user profile, since it's not deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should email the address at the bottom of every page on this one. We need more info on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Which question? I can see three likely contenders:

- ".htaccess settings, how to make images point to a dynamic page?", which you deleted yourself
- "How to make brosers show the border color I want?"
- "English as second language. How to improve it?"

Any of those? If not, how about a clue?

By default, you can see your own deleted *answers*, but IIRC you need 10k to see *all* deleted  posts (including your own deleted questions, I believe).

Comment: the English one. What should I do to see my deleted questions? I don't find it in the usual view...

Comment: Well, no... it has been deleted(ish). You could *try* the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441651) but I doubt it'll work. Ultimately, it simply isn't programming related, so I'm not in a *hurry* to undelete it. I'll happily send you the text if you want it to post somewhere more suitable.

Comment: I'd thank you very much. Anyway I wanted to add content, did someone deleted it? Because I think there was no need to delete it, ok maybe it could stay close... Does the system automatically delete closed question? Why can't I see deleted question I asked? I should be able to.

Maybe Jeff can answer this, thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little surprised [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441651/english-as-second-language-how-to-improve-it-closed) (for those with enough rep to see it) got deleted so soon after being closed.  I'm leaning towards opening it back up, but we should be prepared for a bevy of slippery-slope arguments against it.  People seem to think questions like this open the door to "what's your favorite snack food for programming?"  I'm in favor of this question because, as Jeff has very publicly stated in the past (and I tend to agree), learning to communicate in English will help you become a better programmer.  Anything that helps people become a better programmer should be allowed (within reason, of course).  "Favorite snack food" doesn't carry that property.

Comment: It's a *great* question, but isn't really programming-related. At all. I have to assume there are better places to seek advice on learning English than a Q&A site for programmers, and the answers seem to bear this out: a mix of personal anecdotes and generic advice. Contrast with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language, which could be a similarly general question but instead targets a specific, on-topic (for Meta) need and received correspondingly relevant answers.

Comment: @Shog9: I agree that the question isn't specific to programming at all.  I think Andrea's motivation for asking is to become a better programmer though, so I'm willing to cut some slack.  I wonder if there's a way to rephrase the question to make it more programming-specific?  Surely programming-language syntaxes (syntaxi?) present special challenges to non-native English speakers?

Comment: @Bill: yeah, i think something like that ("How can I learn English programming idioms?", "How might I improve my ability to communicate technical information to English-speaking colleagues?"...) could survive.

Comment: The question is set to community wiki, and it has been improved a lot since I asked it. I understand that maybe it's not _strictly_ programming related, but there is a real reason to delete it?

Comment: Your favorite snack food is very important! Without the proper snack food, you will lose concentration and produce buggy code!