# Complex questions receive little attention - advice?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, unanswered-questions, self-answer, tumbleweed-badge

Several times of late, I've managed to post total [tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed) questions that received no votes, no favorites, no comments, and no answers. Two of them I ended up kind-of answering days later (I couldn't wait for an answer, they needed to get done, figured I might as well post the partial result.) However, I'm looking in retrospect and wondering why they received so little attention. Are they just so specific that no one had an answer, or have I structured them in such a way as to make them intractable?

The above question is related to [this other one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32695/crafting-complex-questions-in-a-way-to-appeal-to-the-masses) but I'd like an answer specific to my questions if possible, especially since the question about unanswered questions didn't really receive an answer that will help me here. Ironic. :-)

> "Tumbleweed" questions in question:
>
> - [PyAMF (0.6) doesn't seem to include Django (1.2) ForeignKey related-objects on auth.models.User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182738/pyamf-0-6-doesnt-seem-to-include-django-1-2-foreignkey-related-objects-on-au)
> - [Proper MXML Class Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293024/proper-mxml-class-factory)
> - [Flex 4 + Django: Testing and Release Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525820/flex-4-django-testing-and-release-options)
> - [Flash + pyAMF + Django session cookie security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553376/flash-pyamf-django-session-cookie-security)

Answer (score 2):

With the exception of possibly the first one on your list, I don't think it's that your questions are too complex, but that they are too localized. In each of them (again, with the exception of the first question), you have a lot of exposition describing your specific use-case, which narrows down the field of experts on your question to likely one person: you.

You could try generalizing or limiting the scope of your questions to make it answerable by people who are not deeply familiar with your current scenario but are experts in the technologies you are using.

Comment: isn't it considered proper use-case to explain the exact problem? actually, #2 and #4 are fairly straightforward, with an important question followed by background exposition... do you think i should make a strong attempt to separate out the base question from the background?

Comment: i agree with Mark... some questions just won't receive the attention quick enough. Questions marked Java C++ C# SQL etc will likely receive greater attention because they are in greater use.

Comment: @eruciform, yes, I do. The purpose of expository information is to narrow the field of inquiry to get the most appropriate answer, but I think you've gone too far, thus limiting the expert pool from which you can draw. You should narrow down the questions, but phrase them in a way that allows people to provide an answer with minimal knowledge of the surrounding circumstances.