# What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?

Tags: support, faq, question-quality, quality-filter, rejected-questions

While trying to ask a question, I got the error message

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

- Why am I getting this message?
- What can I do to get the system to accept my question?
- Can you be more specific?
- What are good resources on how to ask high-quality questions?

> For more information, see ["Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error) in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help).

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

#### Why am I getting this message?

All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for characteristics of extremely poor questions. Your question has been caught by the filter.

#### What can I do to get the system to accept my question?

First, make sure your question is on-topic on the site you're asking it. You can check the site's policy by going to the Help Center, and, under the header 'Asking', going to 'What topics can I ask about here?'.

Make sure your question has

- a clear title
- a reasonable *explanation* of what your question is, **sharing your research on the matter**
- commentary on what you have tried to solve your problem
- correct use of English and actual sentences
- proper spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation

If your question is so brief that it could be looked up in a dictionary or reference book/site trivially, it might not be a good fit on our network.

#### Can you be more specific?

Exact details about the algorithm are not being released by the team.

> I am against being explicit here.... Our check takes into account tags, title and body. We are not going to give breakdown of what was wrong, that is spoon feeding. ([source: waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987))
>
> If we provide a "formula" then it's just another way for users to bypass the question quality filters. ([source: Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91321#91321))

#### What are good resources on how to ask high-quality questions?

Fortunately, there are lots! See:

- [The "How to Ask" page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (the link is basically the same page on every site)
- [How to ask a smart question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question/18588#18588)
- [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)
- [What’s the best way to ask a question if English isn't your first language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/whats-the-best-way-to-ask-a-question-if-english-isnt-your-first-language)
- [Jon Skeet's *Writing the perfect question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) (will take a few minutes to read)
- [Eric Raymond's *How To Ask Questions The Smart Way*](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html), (this gets cited a lot but it's fairly long)

Comment: Ever heard of trial and error?

Comment: This is so wrong :/ I have a page-long question that i think contains everything it needs, nothing simmilar exists anywhere on the internet, and now you are telling me in the most generic way that "something" is wrong with it and that i should figure it out myself. Tell me where exactly is the problem ffs, i'm at work, i can't spend a day experimenting and trying to reverse-engineer your algorithm to find out which particular formulation you did not like.

Comment: "All new questions are subjected to a "minimum quality" filter that checks for characteristics of extremely poor questions. Your question has been caught by the filter." If you don't want to answer the question because you don't want people to game the system, then just say so, This response insults the reader's intelligence.

Comment: I think there are so many old question that doesn't bypass this "minimum quality" filter

Comment: [Eric Raymond's *How To Ask Questions The Smart Way*](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) is ***very*** obsolete and contains a lot of confusing information which is clearly wrong for the Stack Exchange of today. It should not be linked - or even mentioned -  in this Community Wiki answer.

Comment: Why should it be in correct English?? it does not sound nice, when communities from all over the world are participating the knowledge why it is for English speaking only?? I have see this many time that people with poor English ask the question and they get down vote, this not a place to correct and beautiful language you have to define your primary goal, question is important upper and lower case are not that important, for sure its good to write in a correct manner,  positive way could be to correct if you see any mistake, we can't identify the cause of poor wr we should not make it a base.

Comment: I think by correct English, the moderator is actually saying not Elaborated English but Understandable, and it's valid. (ifs gonna ask lk dat.. will be hard to understand)