# "It does not meet our quality standards" error message Is more like a bug

Tags: support, question-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I am asking questions about Mediawiki just like users do about CakePHP, Codeigniter and others but I just get

> It does not meet our quality standards.

Why? Asking about mediawiki is bad thing or do I need to write a long long description of my question when it can be explained in a simple sentence?

Unfortunately Mediawiki doesn't have a large support group (I guess) thats why I resort to SO for asking help but I am just being stuck by not knowing what I need to correct in the question to meet the quality standard

---

This is what I posted as a question.

> mediawiki, how to modify search results to show if a page has sub pages?

plenty of down votes, can i ask why?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/147333. If you think the question is relevant please put it in this question

Comment: i have already read that, and if i am correct my question meets all the requirements, it is clear, it is explained and it uses correct english sentences

Comment: Can you show the question you tried to post?

Comment: mediawiki, how to modify search results to show if a page has sub pages? simple as this

Comment: @user503148: Yes, I can see why you have this problem. This is a very poor question and in combination with your writing style a perfect example which will be downvoted and closed as not a real question. You're lacking key information like versions used, what you mean with sub pages and especially what you've tried so far.

Comment: what i posted was just a title, do i need to mention all this in the title itself?

Comment: @user nope. What do you have in your question body? Re the downvotes, downvoting is a sign of disagreement on Meta rather than a judgement on quality. I assume 8 people (including myself) disagree with this being a bug

Comment: Once again, your title attracted all the attention. You really should work on that... This is *not* a bug. It worked correctly in this case. If you want tips on how to *improve* the question, you need to actually post the question you tried to ask.

Answer (score 10):

As per the comments, the question you tried to ask was

> mediawiki, how to modify search results to show if a page has sub pages?

that questions like that get rejected is by design. It is not a good question by Stack Overflow's standards.

What you can do to improve your chances is pad the question with relevant information like:

- Tell people what version you are using.
- Tell people what template you are using (if applicable).
- Make an example of how you create subpages - it may not be obvious to everyone.
- Show what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck.
- Mention any manuals, references and tutorials you may already have looked at.
- Mention any template files you have tried to apply the customization to.

Comment: all this needs to be written in the body, am i write?

Comment: @user, you are right, yes.

Comment: i wrote it and it didn't work, can you please explain why?

Comment: @user503148: No, we can't unless you show us the exact question you tried to post.

Comment: ok i will try to recreate it i dont quite remember it now

Comment: I recommend staying away from stackoverflow.  I have attempted to post MANY questions an not one has been accepted.  Find a real forum.

Comment: @Clem if the automatic quality filter blocks your contributions, there *usually*  is a good reason for it. Not always, but most of the time. Can you post an example?