# Ask A Question should remove whitespace before checking for validity of message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, whitespace

The inclusion of extraneous whitespace is not a likely indicator of a good question. This is evidenced by the remarks of one or more users that "I added a few carriage returns and it let me post the question".

Either a question appears to be sufficient or it does not.

Comment: I feel a sense of deja vu. Has this been asked or discussed here before, in a different way? If it has, could you please link it? Thanks.

Comment: Same same, but different http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96588/what-is-wrong-with-single-paragraph-questions @rob

Answer (score 8):

Good idea!

I'll strip excess lines (including lines of all whitespace) before running this check.

`(?:^\s*\r?\n$){2,}`