# How does Stackoverflow measure "quality"?

Tags: discussion, support, posting, question-quality

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)
>   [Should the metrics used to filter good and bad questions be opened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97475/should-the-metrics-used-to-filter-good-and-bad-questions-be-opened)
>   [Make the "Sorry, we can't accept this question" message more helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/)

Sometimes when asking a question I get the message, "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: It does not meet our quality standards."

How is "quality" measured?

Comment: See here related discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97475/should-the-metrics-used-to-filter-good-and-bad-questions-be-opened

Comment: And the [FAQ entry](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) here on Meta.

Comment: The exact algorithm is closed-source to prevent gaming. I can't say anything more about it than that. Please have a look at the links already provided; there are enough clues in those posts to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It's all answered here:
[Make the "Sorry, we can't accept this question" message more helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91253/make-the-sorry-we-cant-accept-this-question-message-more-helpful/91987#91987)

If you truly believe what you ask is not low quality and it's still blocked, post it here for others to review. (I mean edit your question with it, don't add new question)