# Can the reason for a system rejection of an edit be shown?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the metrics used to filter good and bad questions be opened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97475/should-the-metrics-used-to-filter-good-and-bad-questions-be-opened)

When attempting to edit this post *[Why would one use the ChannelFactory to instantiate a WCF proxy rather than a Service Reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048992/why-would-one-use-the-channelfactory-to-instantiate-a-wcf-proxy-rather-than-a-se)*, my edit was rejected with this message:

[image]

The problem is that this tells me nothing. I presume the edited post contains something that has violated a validation type filter, but what exactly is the problem? Can the rejection reason be shown?

I simply tried to replace the *bit.ly* shortened URL the OP used with the actual URL of the blog post he was referencing (this one: http://dotnetrobert.com/?q=node/115).
Note that this was a direct edit, not a suggested edit, and it is one that I have done successfully many times before - this is the first time I have seen this message. This is possibly the same issue the OP himself alludes to in his comments.