# Problems posting questions

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

When I tried to post my question, it says my question does not meet the quality standards and hence doesn't let me post.

My question was:

> My iPad application displays a set of PDFs, png images and .mov video
>   files. All these files are stored in my Xcode project bundle, and i am
>   accessing it from there. When i am installing the app in my device, is
>   it possible to hack and access those files?  If so, i would like to
>   encrypt them before adding it to my Xcode project bundle, and decrypt
>   them from within the source code when i am reading and displaying
>   those files. How can i do it??  Thanks in advance.

What part of it does not meet your standards?

Answer (score 14):

- The word "I" is always capitalized in written English.
- You only need one question mark to end a sentence.
- You didn't post any code.  What have you tried so far?
- Your question is only a single paragraph.  Short questions are an indicator of little prior research being done.  What did you find out when you researched this problem on your own?

Also, when your question gets rejected you're linked to a page on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) questions.  There are suggestions there on what to do.

Comment: Also, the "Thanks in advance." bit at the end could be dropped.