# Asking Question Feature Disabled plus People Votes Down My Answer Though I Answer Perfectly

Tags: support, down-votes, users, user-accounts

I am new to Stack Overflow and found out that people of this community are really very rude and non supportive.

People who have privileges to vote down are making wrong use of it. I asked 2-3 questions differently and they put it closed saying Duplicate Question. They Were totally different questions and method or idea for that question was totally different.

Also someone posted one question with his whole project code in zip file I downloaded his project, ran and suggested possible errors. People with power of downvote gave me minus for my answer which was totally ridiculous. Have a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742406/can-someone-tell-why-my-app-is-crashing/6742525#6742525

I also answered few questions and got plus points, which means I am not spamming here. [How to 'show current line' in in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490518/how-to-show-current-line-in-in-xcode-4/6731592#6731592)

I have only one question to you admin fellows that: Is this your approach to treat NOOBS on Stack Overflow? If this behavior continues soon your site will lose reputation. I am greatly disappointed by your people's behavior. Hope you will understand my problem and treat my question positively

Comment: There is nothing "rude" about downvotes. That's a big part of how this site works. If you don't like it, you're free to go elsewhere.

Comment: inb4 tears:Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement. And for Pete's sake, Please Don't Type Like This. It Is Really Irritating To See. And Fix.

Comment: To echo Sathya, Please Don't Type This Way, it's very annoying. Please, also, don't call members of (M)SO "NOOB"s. While there are certainly a number of novice programmers there are also a number of very exepreinced ones, so don't apply the noob tag where it is not justified. And downvoted in this case are probably down to grammer, spelling, *disagreement* and use of words.

Comment: Boo to your question, but yay to the fact that you, as a new user, recognized that you should come here to ask about StackOverflow.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: So today after 10 months I am visiting this again. With decent reputation on SO. I really feel I was wrong and stupid. I was fresh out of college new to this world and unaware of rules and regulations. What i posted here was wrong. Today I vote down and flag this kind of posts. So I apologize to all for becoming a mess 10 months ago. I admit it.. :-))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a site where technical merit is most important. You were recently downvoted on an answer because you told someone to stop using `strong` which (according to a comment) is a new feature in iOS 5. So you didn't know of this feature yet and told him to stop using it. If he's developing for iOS 5, then that's simply *wrong*: he *should* use the features that the platform provide.

For this, your *answer* has been down-voted. Note that this is not a personal attack on yourself, but rather a vote on how useful/correct that answer is for this particular question.

Don't take offense by downvotes, but try to understand why you are being downvoted instead.

Comment: @ Sauer : I agree but I checked references and then only answered..also as per one user's comment this coding secret till now and not declered by Apple for public..so its obvious i will be unaware of it...and i just suggested to use retain instead of strong..If he is developing for iOS 5 he should have mentioned it..Otherwise anyyone will consider iOS 4 development..

Comment: @patel: again: it's not a judgement of yourself. The answer wasn't perfect for the given situation (even when he *didn't* mention he developed for iOS5, others have infered it). No one said you **must** know all that and the asker *might* have been able to be clearer about it. But someone probably thought "this answer can be misleading, if the OP is asking about iOS 5, so it's not good here".

Comment: Btw Source code wasn't supposed to be posted publicly..So there is no question of misleading .. it must be for apple official people only..

Comment: @patel: that all might be true, but it doesn't matter: Your answer was *not* correct, from a purely technical point of view and therefore it was voted down. There's nothing more to it.

Answer (score 10):

> People who have privileges to vote down are making wrong use of it.

I disagree. You have received probably 2 or 3 downvotes. Hardly a misuse.

> They Were totally different questions and method or idea for that question was totally different..

The idea was same of the question was same. I'd have closed it as Not A Real Question. Your question was essentially plz-give-me-teh-codez. There's no hint of what you've done/what you have tried. It was probably closed as possible duplicate to give you a hint at what to look for.

> Again This people with power of downVote gave me minus for my answer which Was totally ridiculous..

The downvotes that you have received is best explained by the comment:

> these (strong/autorelease) are iOS 5.0 enhancements and part of the templates (and strictly speaking still under NDA, thus @thesparkman should not be posting this source publicly). more particularly, part of Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

– [bshirley 2 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742406/can-someone-tell-why-my-app-is-crashing/6742525#comment-7990740)

Some people don't agree with the concept of breaking NDAs.

> I have only one question to you admin fellows that: Is this your Approach to treat NOOBS on S.O.??

Admins don't treat anyone "unfairly", heck they don't treat anyone at all. The community votes on all answers. You've got some upvotes indicating good answers. You should learn from the downvotes and not take it personally.

> I am greatly disappointed by your people's behavior

Which people? I don't see any "disappointing" behaviour. Is it disappointing to have your good answers upvoted? Is it disappointing to have vague questions closed? I think not.

Comment: if I received "merely" 2 or 3 downvotes then why I can't ask questions?? my problem that..

Comment: @patel.rohn how do you mean disabled? Do you get "It does not meet our quality standards”? If so read this -> http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/133693

Comment: "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"

Comment: @patel.rohn refer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998

Comment: So today after 10 months I am visiting this again. With decent reputation on SO. I really feel I was wrong and stupid. I was fresh out of college new to this world and unaware of rules and regulations. What i posted here was wrong. Today I vote down and flag this kind of posts. So I apologize to all for becoming a mess 10 months ago. I admit it.. :-))

Comment: @anonymous good to hear that you've realized your mistake & have corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

First off, there is nothing "rude" about downvotes. Voting is a big and important part of how this site works, and it is important to point out that there is **no such thing** as "wrong" downvotes. People are free to downvote posts for whatever reasons they like. They're also under no obligation to explain to you why they've chosen to cast a downvote. Anonymity is guaranteed. If you don't like this system, you're free to go elsewhere.

But let's look at some of the specific examples you cite. You say [your answer to an Objective C question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742406/can-someone-tell-why-my-app-is-crashing/6742525#6742525) was downvoted, "which Was totally ridiculous". I disagree. In that case, people even left *comments* explaining why they thought your answer was wrong or misleading. I personally don't know anything about Objective C, so I can't actually comment on whether those people are right or wrong, but it appears to me that `strong` and `@autoreleaspool` are important language keywords and something worth knowing about. Including them is not wrong or a mistake as your answer suggests.

The other thing I can tell, even without having much knowledge of Objective C, is that your answer isn't particularly helpful in answering the question. You haven't formatted code samples appropriately, so they are difficult to read. You also haven't used the correct markdown syntax to create a numbered list, so that looks sloppy and difficult to read as well. You also don't explain what is *wrong* with the code, or why these mistakes are causing errors. You just propose an alternative way of writing it. That's great if people want to just copy and paste code off of the Internet, but real developers don't do that. They try to figure out what *caused* their mistakes, *why* they're causing the problems they see, and how to fix them in the future. Your answer doesn't really help anyone do that.

You say that "I also answered few questions and got plus points, which means I am notspamming Here.." To my knowledge, no one has accused you of spamming. Downvotes do not indicate spam; we have spam flags for that, and spam answers are automatically deleted from the site. Yes, you provided an answer that appears to be helpful to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490518/how-to-show-current-line-in-in-xcode-4/6731592). Good for you. You got 2 upvotes for it. That doesn't prove anything about the quality of the *rest* of your contributions.

Downvotes are **not** cast against **users**, they're applied against **individual posts**. Proving that *some* of your contributions have been good or helpful is not a reason that *others* of your contributions should not be downvoted.

> Is this your Approach to treat NOOBS on S.O.?? If this behavior continues soon your site will lose Reputation. I am greatly disappointed by your people's behavior. Hope you will understand my problem and treat my question positively..

Yes. If "NOOBS" give answers that are incorrect or misleading, **those answers will and should be downvoted**. Again, that's how the site works. Voting is in large part intended to provide a mechanism of assessing the technical merit of responses. If you don't know the answer and can't help, then you probably shouldn't post an answer to that question. If you do, you indeed run the risk of being downvoted.

And yes, downvotes do cost you reputation. But only a few points. You lose 2 points for having an answer downvoted, but you gain **10** points for having an answer upvoted. A few upvotes more than make up for a couple of downvotes.

None of this is to say that "NOOBS" are unwelcome here. But whining about downvotes *is* quite unwelcome. The other thing that's unwelcome are "plz-give-me-teh-codez" questions. This is not that kind of a site. Questions that include phrases like "Anyone Knows code for that??" are quite likely to be downvoted and closed. Consider yourself warned.

For tips on how to ask questions (and avoid the eventual fate of perpetually low-quality contributors), look here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

Comment: I admire your effort but that two keywords and whole coding is kept confidential by Apple Inc. as its from iOS 5 so it's obvious that 95% of developers do not know about it..

Comment: @patel.rohn: So what? There's no guarantee that 95% of developers know about *anything* on this site. The point is that has **nothing** to do with downvotes.

Comment: ok..But i am not able to ask question..I am n=banned is it permanant??

Comment: @patel.rohn: Read the link at the bottom of the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this

Comment: @patel.rohn - Automatic reference counting is not a well-kept secret.  In fact, the keywords you describe are published on the LLVM website as part of the specification: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property .  It's been an extremely popular topic of discussion among Cocoa developers since WWDC, so I'd doubt that even a majority of iOS developers don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of those who voted down your questions, as well as voted to close two of them as duplicates.  I used to give comments when I did this, but the iPhone-related tags have been flooded with bad questions and there just isn't enough time in the day to do so any more.

You started by asking a [fairly unclear question about performing undo / redo in an OpenGL ES drawing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689600/undo-drawing-in-paint-application-opengl-by-storing-image-in-buffer), but then rather than cleaning that up to get better answers, you proceeded to post two [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690462/can-i-use-nsundomanager-to-undo-drawing-in-paint-application-closed) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692907/create-an-array-of-buffer-in-opengl-closed) asking the same thing, separated by only two hours each.  Yet another [downvoted question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632650/images-lost-during-pdf-to-epub-conversion) is asking about how to convert a PDF to an ePub using software tools, which is not a programming question and is off topic for the site (I voted to move this to Super User, but did not vote it down).  Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556545/send-e-mail-from-an-application-ios-4-0-and-above)  is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184179/iphone-how-to-send-email-from-iphone-withouth-use-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-cl), among others, and didn't have a clear title explaining the issue.  Quite frankly, your [previous Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98535/135615) wasn't too clear either.

In regards to your answer, it is wrong, as others have explained.  `strong` and `@autoreleasepool` are [valid in LLVM 3.0 under automatic reference counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html), and if the asker was to implement your suggestion they would get compiler errors.  Usually, when I encounter something in code that I haven't seen before, I look it up.  If I can't find it in a simple search, that's usually enough to pique my curiosity and I go digging deeper.  I try to avoid answering something where I don't recognize elements within the code.

At no point was anyone rude to you.  In fact, by asking three repeated questions in the span of a few hours, you were doing something that would not be appropriate in any mailing list or discussion forum I know.  On Stack Overflow, this behavior is curbed by heuristics like the one you encountered.  The very controls you say will lead to the site losing reputation are what have kept it from degenerating like all of the other forums and mailing lists I've seen over the years.

Asking questions on Stack Overflow is a privilege, not a right.  In the eyes of the community, you abused that privilege and so are unable to ask more questions.  You still have the ability to help others out, and we encourage you to do so.  You also still can search through the many, many questions that have been asked in this area.  Many of the things you have asked here have answers somewhere on the site, so you still should be able to learn what you need to do your work.

Comment: +1 Agree with this. And thanks for taking the time to post an answer that discusses the specific posts in their proper context.

Comment: So today after 10 months I am visiting this again. With decent reputation on SO. I really feel I was wrong and stupid. I was fresh out of college new to this world and unaware of rules and regulations. What i posted here was wrong. Today I vote down and flag this kind of posts. So I apologize to all for becoming a mess 10 months ago. I admit it.. :-))

Answer (score 1):

I think SO has a learning curve and most of the new users need some time to understand the way SO works, how to ask questions, how to answer questions and which question to answer.

Every post on SO will be read very quickly by many people with a good expertise in that particular area, thats the great thing here, and if they don't agree they will downvote ([See here: Vote down questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) I have never experienced wrong downvotes). Thats part of the review process and that makes SO so helpful.
But in my experience most of the users will only downvote if the answer is really wrong or for other reasons not helpful. Often you will get comments on what is wrong. You can try to improve your answer, just leave it and go to the next or maybe even delete it.

So don't be disappointed by your first downvotes, try to learn from them and improve the next time. You already got upvotes! Thats good.

Some helpful links:

- [how-to-ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- [how-to-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)
- [Jon Skeet: Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- [Jon Skeet: Answering technical questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx)

Comment: Ya but I can not ask questions any more.. Disabled..