# Stack Overflow: "It does not meet our quality standards."

Tags: support, questions, answer-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

After this filter got added to the Stack Exchange sites I have been spending a half hour or more to post a simple question. What is the purpose of it? Stack Overflow used to be a good place to come and post questions and get immediate answers but now its becoming a waste of time.

Can someone open a new exchange for people who are having problems trying to submit something so that we can all figure out why our questions won't post?

BTW, this is the question I have been trying to post on Stack Overflow, and it's not passing the filter check. What am I doing wrong?

```
title: opera browser specific css tags

content: 
where can i find a list of opera specific css tags? 
i have googled for hours and cannot find a list of them. 
I do know that they start with `-o- {   }`
```

Comment: http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto27/css/o-vendor/

Comment: *"After this filter got added to the Stack Exchange sites I have been spending a half hour or more to post a simple question. What is the purpose of it?"* See the first sentence. We **want** you to spend more time composing questions. That makes the questions and the site overall better. Thanks, this question provides confirmation that the system is working precisely as intended.

Comment: sure cody. if your purpose is to attract more english majors than programmers, then yeah i'd say it's working precisely as intended.  good luck buddy.  if this keeps up, i'll just go elsewhere.  quality should be measured by how much programming sense a question makes, not by spell checking and punctuations.

Comment: @Riz: It does not take an English major to capitalize the word "I" and the first letter of a sentence. We're not talking about some obscure grammar rule or something. This is basic stuff that anyone is taught about constructing a sentence in English. It is not an onerous request for people to use a reasonable subset of the actual English language.

Comment: @Riz: No, we require you to employ professionalism to use proper grammar and punctuation in your posts. This is not at all unreasonable. If you think that someone needs to be "an English major" to construct two professional-looking paragraphs, then that's a concern.

Answer (score 5):

Well for a start you are using lower case "i" instead of upper case "I" when referring to yourself.

Your question title isn't actually a question.

Then there's not a great deal of content to your post.

Comment: thanks, it seemed to have worked for now. but would meta be a good place to ask why my question isnt being posted? or would a future exchange open up for that?

Comment: @Sarmen - theoretically yes (but only the once), I would read the question that this one has been closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @Sarmen, I would consider it inappropriate for you to ask about your question every single time this happens. Just follow the simple advice set out at the post that your question was closed as a duplicate of.