# What does the "does not meet our quality standards" error message mean?

Tags: support, asking-questions, question-quality, rejected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I just want to post the following question with the title of:

> an mvc3 project take a long time to compile

and a tag of [asp.net-mvc-3](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-3) and the following text:

> first of all, i am a beginner in web programming. second , i searched about my problem but results was obscure for me. so please help me in the simplest manner
>   i have an mvc3 project and when i compile it (f5) it will switch to browser and then it take a long time to show me the result!
>   by the way i have iis7 installed on my windows7. but do not know if it needs to add something to iis7 or publish my project or etc...?

But I was not able to post it. My submission was blocked with the following error:

> It does not meet our quality standards

Why?

Comment: `"Why might my ASP.NET MVC project take a long time to compile?"` compare that to your title, and think about what makes one different from the other.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm the filter uses is not publicly available, but we can make some guesses.  Try some capitalization.  The pronoun 'I' and proper names of products should be capitalized.  Start with that.

Remember, this is a formal question that's being posted to your programming colleagues.  It is not a text message you are sending to your friend.

Comment: oh hai thar k thx 4 replyin 2 my Q! i will try 2 be more gooder @ grammar now

Comment: @Cody LOL You should always spell it "grammer" as in, "there's nothing wrong with my grammer".

Comment: yes you right "WINDOWS7" and "IIS7" must be capitalized

Comment: @Rzassar Well, "Windows7" would work, but yes.  It's a worthwhile investment of your time because people will take your question more seriously and they will give you a better quality answer as a result.

Comment: Damn! You're right. I *tried* to misspell grammar, but my fingers just wouldn't let me. (Also, is anyone else a bit concerned that Rzassar's last comment might be completely serious...?)

Comment: could we get the algorithm to be made publically accessible please? (so people could know *how* to improve their questions?)

Comment: @user143747 No, as that would provide a way to work *around* the algorithm.  Just use your best judgement in writing your questions and there will be no problem and, if need be, read other people's questions that have passed the filter.