# Why can't I ask "Why there is no "++" operator in Ruby?" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I'm trying to ask the question in title, 
but got

> "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>   * It does not meet our quality standards"

What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see:

- It's short
- It's maybe subjective and argumentative
- It maybe misses an definitive answer
- It may trigger (unnecessary) discussion
- It's a duplicate: [Why doesn't Ruby support i++ or i-- (increment/decrement operators)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3660563/why-doesnt-ruby-support-i-or-i-for-fixnum)