# How do I go about asking a question that the system considers acceptable?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I've had some questions rejected for low quality. What are some tips on phrasing a question so it gets through?

Comment: Show an example, people here usually have good advice on what to do

Comment: @Collin: Would the page linked to above be more helpful to link to than the "How to Ask" page, or did you just not see that page before?

Answer (score 1):

The [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page is linked in the sidebar when you're typing in your question.