# Show which specific quality standard is being violated

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, question-quality

When a user posts a question on Stack Overflow and his question is rejected with the following message, `It does not meet our quality standards`, then the specific quality standards should be shown to the user just below the above error.  It can be really annoying sometimes, we keep on editing our titles and our content is still being rejected because of quality standards.  Why should a user have to search through the `what are stackoverflow quality standards` page?  Why waste his time,

**just show the specific quality standards that are being violated**.

Comment: If you know the specific problem, it encourages you to attempt to get around it / game the system. If you don't, all you can do is make an honest attempt to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Let me know if you think my editing changed your question too much.

Comment: @Popular, I tripped over Bill's reopening, and I had some huge internet access problems.  So mostly my fault.  I hate wireless.

Comment: Ok my apologies for asking this question. But the purpose of my post was to help newcomers by mentioning that why his question is rejected again and again and for what reasons. As some user mentioned one tip `There is a distinct lack of capitalization. Please capitalize the first word of each sentence when appropriate.` and that really work for me. The question is why not to show this tip there when the question was rejected?? On [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) it is not mentioned that what are Stack Overflow quality standards.

Answer (score 15):

> why a user has to search for what are stackoverflow quality standards?

Because we want you to read and understand the [quality standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask).  [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards/92075#92075).

Those standards are already linked in the sidebar when you get to the "low quality" message, so there's no need for you to search for them.

Comment: I don't know if it already does this but perhaps the links that you gave could appear with this message?

Comment: @ConradFrix I just checked to verify, the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) link does appear in the sidebar when you trip the "low quality" alarm. (And once you get to that page, there are several more links in the Related sidebar.)

Comment: No sorry, that didn't help me solve my problem in any way. I read the standards and understand them.

Answer (score 4):

From your current question on Meta I can see at least one problem:

- There is a distinct lack of capitalization. Please capitalize the first word of each sentence when appropriate.

Additionally, titles are not the ultimate arbiter of a quality question. If you include excessive shorthand--e.g. u or thx--in the body text your question may be rejected.

Without seeing the content of your question it is hard to say why it was rejected exactly.

Comment: He isn't asking for the specifc for his question, see my editing.

Comment: Perhaps the fact it needed editing to show a clear question proves his point...

Comment: He definitely needed help.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the exact same error message when trying to ask a question on a meta site.

After taking a look here to see if that happened to anyone else, I was amazed to read the kind  of answers `Aamir Adnan` received from the majority!

The question I asked was perfectly clear, in a perfectly good (or at least very understandable ) English.

Nothing on the *How to ask a question* page (for which the link is not shown when the error appears or probably hidden somewhere) helped solve the problem.

Thinking the post might be too short (2 sentences, that's all I needed to ask a clear question, adding more would have made me look retarded) I simply added a lot of rubbish and it finally got accepted. (talk about quality standards...)

Of course I edited afterwards and removed the gibberish. Since it got edited very quickly after the submit, no traces were left of the original post.

So I repeat `Aamir Adnan`'s question: **What are these quality standards you are referring to?**

When the title is too short, I get a clear message telling me to put more than 15 characters. Why doesn't it work for the body of the question?

Additionally some of the comments here are extremely rude and very close to racism. One of them native speaker who comments on "good English" uses an even poorer language than the OP.

Sad.

Comment: Hope for the best for what happend to me may not happen to you :-) As your question is same as mine.

Answer (score -3):

It shouldn't have to be guesswork to figure out when you've done something wrong.

Some non-english-using users just haven't learned all the rules for good grammar, and have to be educated.

**Correction should be specific, when possible, so that a user can correct his behavior.**
Specific correction is always better than general guidelines.

Comment: People who trip over the quality filters and can't figure out how to improve their questions without detailed hand-holding are unlikely to ever improve enough to be productive citizens of Stack Overflow. [How to Ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) has all the information they need to ask a good question that doesn't run afoul of the filters.

Comment: If someone need to learn how to write good english before posting, then they to learn it, not just be told about a single missing capital letter.   Otherwise we will get lots of post that **just** pass the check.

Comment: @Ian, `To learn` means that they need to be educated.  Every Error and Warning should be education users at all times.  The best education is the education that specifically addresses a problem.

Comment: Lance, this is the same problem as trying to teach people how to use Excel when they don't know the difference between the left mouse button and the right. You know what I'm talking about, because I know you've tried... the sheer mountain of detail that you have to provide quickly becomes overwhelming. The answer is: go find a good book on Excel and study it. Learn what the mouse does.  It's the same advice we give everyone who writes bad questions: go do the leg work you should have already done, and then come back here and try again. In other words, stop being lazy.

Comment: `@lance` By your answer it mean that if a person don't knows good English grammar then he should not post his question no matter if he is stuck and can't get out of it without being helped. Then what is the purpose of `Editing` option? We are not writting stories here, we are asking for help. And if there are small mistakes then that should be accepted and corrected later by `Editing` as some generous people do.

Comment: @Aamir, no that isn't what I meant.  They should learn from their mistakes, and write better questions in the future.  I've edited many hundreds of posts with bad english, and if the poster is paying attention, then he can learn from my edits, how to do better writing.