# Lack of explanation for question that can't be submitted

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show which specific quality standard is being violated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/show-which-specific-quality-standard-is-being-violated)

When posting a question whose content matches the title, you recieve the following warning:

[image: question can't be submitted]

It really should give something more descriptive.

Comment: The screenshot [does not meet our standards](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/) either ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long story short, no. We want people to learn to write questions that are better outright, not just do the minimum to "game" a rule or two and sneak a question that's still actually pretty bad over the quality bar.

This is intended to help the *poster* as much as the regulars on one of the stack exchange sites: The person asking the question probably wants a great answer to their question and the people reading the question can best deliver a great answer when the question itself is a well structured, great quality question that provides as much information as possible and does so as clearly as possible.