# Why does my post "not meet our quality standards"?

Tags: bug, quality-filter

I'm trying to post the following question, but get the

> This post does not meet our quality standards

error, with no explanation of what the problem is

---

### Title

> Grails query cache being ignored

### Body

> I have an application which is read-mostly, so most of my queries use
>   the Hibernate 2nd-level query cache. I have one query that must be
>   executed every time a page loads, so I invoke it from the layout GSP
>   like this:
>
> ```
> ${Book.countByApproved(true, [cache: true])}
> ```
>
> I have enabled the 2nd-level cache for the `Book` class, by adding
>
> ```
> static mapping = {
>     cache true
> }
> ```
>
> to `Book.groovy`. I also have the following configured in
>   `DataSource.groovy`
>
> ```
> hibernate {
>   cache.use_second_level_cache = true
>   cache.use_query_cache = true
>   cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
> }
> ```
>
> In this same file I've enabled query logging by adding `logSql=true`
>   in the `dataSource` block.
>
> Every time I load a page, the `Book.countByApproved(true)` query is
>   logged, so I assume this means that the results are not being
>   retrieved from the query cache? I'm running everything locally, so
>   there's no possibility that the cache is being missed because the
>   cached query results have expired.
>
> I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm using the [Hibernate Filters
>   plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter) and have a default filter configured for the `Book` class.
>   Perhaps there's some issue with using hibernate filters and the query
>   cache?

Comment: That .... looks like an atypical question to hit the quality filter ...

Comment: There could be a rational hatred of books (or questions that might discuss them)...

Comment: I would guess that the title is the problem, you could try some variations on that. But anyway, this looks like it shouldn't be stopped by the filter

Comment: I changed the title to "Grails query cache is ignored" and this is accepted.....wtf?

Comment: Looks like the filter likes complete sentences, and does not consider `being` as being (ha) a proper verb.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well whatever the problem is, at the very least I should be given some info that would help me resolve it

Comment: @Don I believe the lack of info is status-by-design.

Comment: @Don, providing more information about what needs to be fixed was discussed (and shot down) [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/show-which-specific-quality-standard-is-being-violated). You also might want to read [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Comment: Devil's Advocate - What if the quality filter has more false positives when we think - and we just don't hear about them because it's from people's first questions, they get upset that their legitimately good questions are rejected, and leave never to come back rather than ask why on meta (because they don't know about it yet)?

Comment: Have you tried to enter just a few lines, for instance the first paragraphs? Then you can edit the question to add the rest, I guess. A bit like the FGITW approach for answers. Not that it would constitute a valid solution, but just to see what happens.

Comment: I hope these rejections are at least being logged so the developers can look through them for false positives instead of relying on people complaining on Meta.

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced this problem several times, I beleive this is all because of filtering of common words we use in normal talk like 'being' and 'ignored' as your title contains simple words of english instead of technical words, quality meter of stackoverflow gives you that message
Try to use more technical words and it will never irritate you again.

Comment: Still the obvious quality of the content should then offset the perceived lack of quality of the title. Much like a spamfilter will never refuse a mail just because 1 or 2 tests failed, it needs to test a lot that break a threshold together.

Comment: You should have clear, accurate titles.  -1 for encouraging OP to throw more big words in title to get past quality filter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in my mind