# Can't post a question

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I tried to post a question as following:

> Just wondering in C#, if I get the length of an array by array.Length, what's the time complication? Is it O(1) or O(n?

It says "It does not meet our quality standards." Can anybody explain what the problem is here?

Comment: @PopularDemand You rejected that edit while I was improving it, and now my edit summary makes me look insane

Comment: @Jim, I rejected your edit because you fixed the text inside the blockquote. Since this question is about a rejected post, it could have been the cause of the error, and so shouldn't be touched.

Comment: Oh, sorry, @MichaelMrozek. Wait, Michael Mrozek? Never mind, not sorry.

Comment: its O(1).  Any language that has an O(n) algorithm for determining the length of an array should be shot.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too short and the answer is O(1).

Comment: Thanks. Looks like Stack Overflow is not a place to answer short questions. May I ask why it's O(1) or where I can find how array.Length work?

Comment: @truelies - Ah now you see why short posts are bad :D -- It is O(1) because it just needs to look at a property and does not need to iterate over the list.  You can see this in the debugger and with knowledge of standard patterns for implementing arrays.  (That is, you can put a marker at the end or store the size in the object.)

Answer (score 1):

"Just wondering" might be a problem in addition to what Hogan says.  Just ask the question straight up :)

Comment: But it didn't say what's the problem was. I will remove it and see if I can post.

Comment: Just removed "Just Wondering" Still got Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    It does not meet our quality standards.

Comment: Seems it has too much limitation.