# Are some users forced to include code in questions?

Tags: support, new-users, quality-filter

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571625/install-xcode-application-in-ipad-objective-c/8571675#8571675) (see edit history). The asker has formatted the last paragraph of the question as code.

I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564077/same-class-in-different-pages-in-xcode) yesterday (again, see edit history) where an asker had put a complaint about having to include code in as formatted code.

Is this an actual rule? If so, what are the rules and rationale behind it? Is it really helping the quality of the site? Neither question required code, so in both cases someone had to step in and edit it out. The original formatting of the question led to criticism and downvotes (notwithstanding that they were both pretty poor questions, and would have got a number of downvotes anyway).

Perhaps it doesn't apply to new users *per se*, but to users with a string of fairly poor questions?

Comment: This new user doesn't seem to have been required to include code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571934/where-could-i-find-downloadeble-link-for-junit-jar-file-that-contains-the-method

Comment: True enough. I've amended the question slightly - what I want to know is if there are any rules like this, if so how do they work?

Comment: The first asker may have just indented the last paragraph by 4 spaces for some reason without realizing that it formats it as code.  The second may have been responding (inappropriately) to the FAQ: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both users' initial posts were fairly low quality, no proper punctuations or capitalizations etc. I'm pretty sure both ran into the

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - It does not meet our quality standards.

[message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/133693).

The first case, the user decided to pad some words to try to beat the filter.