# my question keeps not meeting the site's quality standards

Tags: support, question-quality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

this is the text of the question , i need an answer and still this is blocking me

we are planning to build an application regarding organ donations , 
we're still not sure about what new technologies we can implement in our project , 
any kind of suggestions is welcomed since our idea is not fully formed yet.
our work will be based on .net technology.

thank you.

what should i do ?

Comment: Try the shift key.

Comment: Even with higher quality, that isn't a real question.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: [status-bydesign]

Answer (score 10):

It's probably blocked because of some combination of the following factors:

- no capitalization
- the words "suggestions" and/or "welcomed"
- "thank you"
- spaces before commas
- no question mark (indicator of there being no actual question, which seems to be true)

Beyond that though, the major flaw is that it's not a real question.  "What technologies can we implement?" is almost completely meaningless, and if answered, how would it be useful?  If you have no idea where to begin on your project, you have bigger problems.

This would probably be closed as Not Constructive or Not A Real Question if posted.

Comment: FWIW, spaces before commas is common in French.

Comment: @R.Martinho: thank you, I always wondered which language it was acceptable to put spaces on both sides of punctuation glyphs.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: not for commas, that's an "error" in French too (no space before a full stop either). We do put a space before : and can put a space before ? or !