# My question does not meet the quality standards

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I'm prevented from asking the below question on Stack Overflow, but I think it is a well formed question.

Stack Overflow gives me the this error message:

> It does not meet our quality standards.

Could it be that the Stack Overflow quality-check needs to be revised?

This is the question I'm trying to ask:

> I need a regular expression for php *preg_match()* function that match an
>   string like below
>
> ```
> monitor22122
> ```
>
> the first part "monitor" is a fixed string but the second part "22122"
>   is a number between 11111 to 99999 can some one give me a good sample
>   for this regex. i found many samples on below website but not help.
>
> [http://regexlib.com/][1]
>
> [1]: http://regexlib.com/

Comment: "i" should become "I".

Comment: Capitals, punctuation are missing. (You're also missing the part where you're supposed to show what you have tried.)

Comment: i correct my question but the problem not solved.

Comment: i think a better way for helping "StackOverflow" is helping me to learn how to ask a question like this and not defending StackOverflow

Comment: Well, actually, keeping such questions out of the system is helping Stack Overflow and the community. You did read the FAQ? You did read the provided link?

Comment: @Bobby yes i read faq but it is completely in general and not helping a user without stackoverflow experience, also which part of my main question is bad?

Comment: The whole question...it can be easily answered with one look into [any of the many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) [documentations](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php).

Answer (score 9):

No, this is not a well formed question.

First of, capitalize *I*, when you're talking about yourself, and use the correct punctuation.
Second, you should show some effort; you should show what you have tried, in order to solve your problem. This is called "give me teh codez" question.
Third, I feel that your question is translated by Google (I am sorry if I'm wrong). In most of the cases, it is wrong.

*By the way, there's no "monitor" in your string above, which you're describing as its fixed part.
*By the way, there's no `regex()` in PHP.

I'd post it as:

> I need a regular expression which would be able to match string below
>
> ```
> service55555
> ```
>
> The first part "service" is a fixed string but the following numbers
>   can be within range 1 - 9 (so 22222 is a valid match).
>
> I have tried to ...., which also failed.

But in this case, I see there's no effort and you should look around a bit more before asking. That's for the next time.

Comment: i reedit that question but my problem exist

Comment: @user986166: Are you serious that you asked such a [poor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482283/regular-expression-for-php) question after asking for an advice ?

Comment: Oh, yeah, before I forget...please do no encourage such questions by posting (C&P ready) examples on how to circumvent that filter. There's a reason that question accumulated 9 downvotes on SO within 9 minutes.

Comment: @Bobby: I saw that. That question has nothing to do with my advices here

Comment: I saw that you saw that...I meant that it's better not to encourage such questions in such ways.

Comment: @Bobby: yeah, I know it already. It's sad.