# What happened to the quality filter?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, quality-filter, community-standards

Look at my [reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/1426955/cole-johnson?tab=reputation). Look at the very beginning where I got more than 1500 reputation in less than a month of being here. I have just barely passed the 3000 mark after 3 months of trying. Why? The quality of questions here.

Recently, the Close Votes queue is always about 50k. Even if they only last a few days, that is still way too much! I have seen questions that are in all lowercase and have no punctuation!

While using the Close Votes queue, I manage to review 40 questions. Every day I've used it, I will close nearly all, with only 1 being left open (2 on a *good day*).

While I've only had the ability to review close votes for 4 days (160 reviews) I've had to close a total of more than 150 questions. Excluding duplicates, that is still *at least* 120 questions!

I love sharing my knowledge with people, but the drop in the quality of posts has made that near impossible. In fact, if you look at my reputation graph, I had spent nearly *3 months* gaining *300 reputation* to go from 2,700 to 3,000 to gain close vote review privileges!

Can we fix this? Or are you going to downvote someone who just wants the quality of the questions to increase?

Here is an [example of a bad question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1973204).

---

<sup>I understand votes mean a different thing here, but please reconsider if you downvoted this before this edit was made</sup>

Comment: What makes you think that all lowercase is correlated to low quality posts?

Comment: Reading through this post I have a different idea of what you're talking about with each paragraph and the title...what is it you want to fix? What is the central problem here?

Comment: I don't see the link between rep graph and the lowercase filter

Comment: What's the connection between your rep and the quality filter?

Comment: What exactly was your train of thought when writing this ?

Comment: @AshRj - stream of consciousness?

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to the asking filter.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter

Comment: [recent tightening of quality filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176875/165773 "announced here") makes me feel that **downvotes on this post are not entirely justified**

Comment: It would be nice if people actually thought about this. I understand votes on Meta mean different things than the main sites, but with the "tightening of the quality filter", it seems _more_ bad questions are getting into the system. That's what this is about. As @gnat said, if you actually thought about this instead of just reading it, you could see what I really am asking.

Answer (score 8):

> Why? The acceptance filter. (not editing)

I don't see what connection your reputation has with the quality filter.

> Recently, the Close Votes queue is always about 50k. Even if they only last a few days, that is still way too much!

This has been brought up many times.

> I have seen questions that are in all lowercase and have no punctuation!

These should be *edited*. You can do that yourself, while it takes 5 people to close a question.

> The filter should require capitalization (or at least not all lowercase) for paragraphs!

Good questions sometimes come from non-native speakers. While this looks good on the outset, outright blocking bad grammar that doesn't affect clarity<sup>1</sup> may not be the best idea.

> We could extend this to require a code block or a fiddle, but there have been some good questions that don't need code.

This has been proposed before, and turned down because "some good questions don't need code".

<sup>1. While it is a bit more annoying to read a paragraph in lowercase, there is no ambiguity imparted to the text due to its bad grammar. Which makes this editable.</sup>

Comment: I'd much rather have all lowercase paragraphs than no paragraphs at all. =D

Comment: @JSteen I would prefer it he other way around. Capitalization fixes are harder to do than a simple <Enter>

Comment: @ColeJohnson: He meant "no text at all".

Comment: @Manisheart are you being sarcastic?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: no. He meant "I'd rather have the user type lowercase text than no text at all". A lot of users dump a bunch of code with no <what I have tried> and <this is what's going wrong> text.