# Why am I being blocked from posting my question?

Tags: support

I can't seem to post the question below. What is wrong with it?

> Title: What is wrong with this jpeg based image compression?
>
> As an assignment i wrote a simple jpg like image compression.
>   But after i encode it ,and decode it the image changes drasticaly.
>   The mDCT() and mIDCT() do the discrete cosine transform and the invers.
>
> For 8-by-8 matrixes i tested them and seem to be ok.
>   But when i use them on a test image i cant figure out whats wrong.
>   The file's can be found here.
>   [Link to files](http://wikisend.com/download/285622/DCT.rar)
>
> Tags: [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) [image](/questions/tagged/image) [jpeg](/questions/tagged/jpeg)

Comment: Capitalize your I's? Add some code?

Comment: You might want to run that through a spell checker. And if you talk about yourself, write "I", not "i". And don't merely link to files. Include the relevant code.

Comment: They [recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter/176875#176875) tweaked the quality filter threshhold for blocking questions. I know it puts a lot of weight on spelling, grammar, and punctuation, and probably takes into account the lack of code in your question too, so try to fix the grammar and punctuation of your sentences, and place the relevant code in your question itself instead of using an external link for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [It does not meet our quality standards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176891/it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) and of [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Answer (score 25):

So, one more time this, ey? Let's go through it...

> What is wrong with this jpeg based image compression?

That's a bad title, it doesn't say anything about the question.

> As an assignment i wrote a simple jpg like image compression. But after i encode it ,and decode it the image changes drasticaly. The mDCT() and mIDCT() do the discrete cosine transform and the invers.

English uses the word `I` to refer to one self, please use your shift key accordingly. Also, the English language uses a space *after* a comma, not before one.

> For 8-by-8 matrixes i tested them and seem to be ok. But when i use them on a test image i cant figure out whats wrong. The file's can be found here. Link to files

Seriously? You expect me to download a rar?! All questions ***need*** to be self-contained and stand on their own. This is not acceptable.

Comment: +1 for the answer, +100 if I could for *You expect me to download a rar?!*.