# Getting "It does not meet our quality standards” need help

Tags: support

So I am trying to post a question (see below), and I get "It does not meet our quality standards". Firstly, this message doesn't even say what part of my question is wrong and, so secondly can you tell me what is wrong?

Title:

> Set the size of a window in openGL(c++)

Text:

> I am creating a basic game in c++ using opengl, I can make a window
>   fine and can make a square appear on the window, as well as being able
>   to make the square move around however  am having trouble getting the
>   window to  be the correct size.
>
> If i try and make the window to be 800 by 600 then the window
>   including the borders will be this size not just the bit inside the
>   border.
>
> I am also having trouble making it so that the square cannot go
>   outside of the area of the screen as the screen seems to be some funny
>   size (about 0.63-to -0.63 instead of -1 to 1).

Comment: Is your shift key broken?

Comment: @Bart I dare say that this question about equal in quality to the average question that actually does get through the filter

Comment: @SamIam Hence the recent tightening of the quality filter. And judging from the questions in the past day or so, I'd say it's doing a decent job.

Comment: They [increased the quality filter threshold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter/176875#176875) yesterday, and although I don't know all the details, I know it does take into account your spelling, grammar, capitalization, and punctuation so try improving that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is lacking significant grammar and has punctuation mistakes. If that is your title, I would take the question mark out. It's also unclear what your question actually is.

Comment: Yep i realised about the title with the question make and changed it. So basicly I can't post because I have a problem where don't know the correct grammar oh great.

Comment: @user2296321: You wrote a crappy question.

Comment: and how could i improve it?

Comment: @user2296321: Use my advice and also read the linked FAQ question above (it's in the duplicate box)

Comment: @user2296321, despite what this answer says the reason is probably because you've posted _no_ code... grammar and spelling is important (and please try to get them right) but even more important is you showing your code so that someone can attempt to help you fix it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Code is not a pre-requisite. I have written questions without code in various tag areas but my questions meet the quality criteria.

Comment: I know @0A0D; I've written answers without code. But, this is the new improved question quality filter and the OP is asking a code question, without code...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Must not apply to 10K+ users, I just copy pasted his question and it passed.

Comment: So i started a new question and it posted fine might have been some sort of bug