# This post does not meet our quality standards, with no reason why

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

I'm getting the above error, but this makes absolutely no sense to me.

- Considering my large site experience, I'm pretty sure that I can at least grasp the basics.
- You could mention *what is wrong with the question*.

[image]

How am I going to fix it if you don't tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That question and answer do not address what to do when the system does not tell you what the error is.

Comment: I guess the problem is it's length. Also, could use a better title. FYI, the quality filter was [turned up a notch recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176875/162704).

Comment: @DeadMG The "no info" is by design afaik.

Comment: @DeadMG: That is *on purpose*. You have an awfully short question there, are you sure you cannot reword that a little? Point to the ABI yuo did find? Explain *why* you need the newer ABI (there could be a work-around for your specific problem)? Etc.

Comment: On the "no reason provided" front, maybe we could just add a link to the canonical duplicate mentioned by Shadow Wizard? It would help any user who cares enough to follow it.

Comment: I'm just making guesses, but some possible triggers are: short length, only a single paragraph, the title contains multiple tags, also the question contains no code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Those details are irrelevant. Either there is a C++11 Itanium ABI or there is not. As for not telling me what's wrong, I'm glad that circlejerking over secrecy is something the devs enjoy, but meanwhile, I'd like to get on and post my question now. But I can't since I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @DeadMG: You *do* know what the problem is. Your post doesn't meet the quality standards.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That is far too vague to be of any practical use. What do you want me to do, spam it full of irrelevant details? I could specify my whole life story in both title and body if you'd like.

Comment: @DeadMG: an extra paragraph with a single sentence containing a single example of why the ABI needs updating for C++11 is very likely more than enough to enable you to post, and actually gives a rationale for your asking this. Surely you have such examples.

Comment: @Mat: I do. But they're irrelevant as to the situation of whether or not the updated ABI exists and whether anyone on SO viewing my question will know of it if it does.

Comment: They're not irrelevant as to _why_ you're asking whether that standard has been updated/revised. Consider it as educating the masses too - not everyone is familiar with why such an update would be necessary (I wasn't until I searched for said update). Motivating your question makes it potentially more interesting to more people who might not have been aware there was an issue at all.

Comment: I've [tweaked the threshold a bit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177416/my-post-does-not-meet-your-quality-standards-can-you-tell-me-why/177425#177425), and this would make it through now. Just a FYI for next time: HTML comments get stripped before the check, so adding lots of woooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooords in comments won't help any.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the question is rather short. Almost a search request. Does the one you've found lack something essential other than not being up to the current standard? [This is rhetorical.]

Comment: Not being up to the current Standard is lacking something essential.

Comment: Add that to the question. ... "rhetorical".

Comment: Why I need an updated version is irrelevant as to whether or not it exists and whether or not anyone knows of it.

Comment: You're missing the point. ... Adding this information would improve the quality of the question. ... Changing *my mind* isn't going to change anything. So it's really pointless to argue with me. This was just a suggestion on something to add which would improve the quality of the question.