# My post does not meet your quality standards. Can you tell me why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, question-quality, quality-filter

This is my [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58632/line-intersection-rendering-in-android) which I tried to post at Stack Overflow. But when I tried to submit it, I got the message

> This post does not meet our quality standards.

I have checked it for 10 minutes, but I can not find if I am wrong. But I can post it at  gis.stackexchange.com

Why does this happen?

Comment: Wait... *that* got blocked by the quality filter? Either I'm missing part of the story here, or somebody set the threshold a bit too high...

Comment: There's no code in your post. What did you try?

Comment: Yes, I can not post it at www.stackoverflow.com. Nobody can imagine what I have suffered to make it submitted. :(

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Are the codes necessary? I am looking for a solution. And why this post can be submitted with no codes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137435/does-android-api-include-google-api-itself

Comment: Yes, if you want people to spend time helping you, show what effort you've put in yourself. I have no idea how that other question got through without code.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Maybe you mean that the codes can make people understand my question easily. Isn't it?  But I think it depends. In my post, it do have no codes related since we have not write the codes before we find a possible solution. So what codes can I post in this case?

Comment: @BilltheLizard While I agree with what you say, I find it hard to believe that the quality filter is able to distinguish between a long question with proper formatting and grammar (and images) apart from a long question with proper formatting and grammar that lacks a "what have you tried" section.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I do not think it is duplicated. Because I just take my un-submitted post as a example. I am not looking for a generic but a concrete  answer to tell me why I am wrong in the post.

Comment: As one of the [moderators has said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177031/why-doesnt-my-question-meet-quality-standards/177087#comment532490_177031), [there are thousands of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176875/) hitting this filter every day; it's not reasonable to expect each one to have a customized response. Further, the same "do your homework" standards apply to Meta questions as to SO questions: have you read the FAQ question I linked? Have you followed the advice? What, very _specifically_, are you having trouble with?

Comment: I read the FAQ, and I have read almost 20 questions related to the quality standards. But I still can not find why I am wrong. I understand what stackoverflow did using the filter, but I just want a clear error response! Just like I am register a email address, and after I fill the email name fields and hit the submit button. You just tell me my email name is invalidate without further information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this yesterday and after 20 painful minutes I realised it was because the first letter in the title was lower case. It looks like this may be your problem too.

Seriously Stack Overflow, way to annoy the best software development community you've done such a brilliant job building over the years....

Whoever wrote/released this filter in its current state needs a bit of a talk IMHO.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125582/how-to-reset-a-thread-pool-efficiently/16125629?noredirect=1#comment23044598_16125629) was my post. Without that 'H' it did "not meet quality standards".

Comment: ps, the model of peer editing should render the need for this kind of check entirely void!

Comment: please don't downvote without a comment.

Comment: Your keyboard is broken or something, weird characters appear where there should be letters

Comment: yes i had a rant, then thought it better being PG.

Comment: @pstanton: You are right. I change the first letter of the title to upper case. And it is submitted.

Comment: Now I'm wondering how the hell [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137880/use-spree-application-layout-in-a-new-controller) got passed the quality filter... It also has a lower case first title word and has a pretty crappy body as well.

Comment: The filter is to be improved. :)

Comment: [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16138797/1369235) starting with small `h`. @Mysticial

Comment: Had to add at least one line of code for the filter to approve, although the question wasn't about programming at all. :facepalm:

Answer (score 10):

FWIW: I've dialed back the threshold on this check a bit, since [I didn't take title quality into account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter/176875#176875) when I recently analyzed the data to determine an appropriate value.

Since title quality counts for up to a third of the total quality score, small problems with a title can have a large impact on an otherwise-decent post. While I certainly think you *should* put a bit more work into titles (capitalization and specific details make them much more enjoyable to read), the current guidance for this particular error doesn't make this obvious enough to avoid frustration.

Comment: "small problems with a title can have a large impact on an otherwise-decent post" - that's the key phrase here.

Comment: At the (new, new) threshold, you pretty much have to check all the boxes (short, no caps, all one misspelled word, etc) to damn an otherwise top-scoring post. I'll try to collect data on title quality sometime next week to see if this can be tweaked further, but for now I think it will suffice.

Comment: I got it, that's to say you can not tell people exactly why his post does not meet your quality standards.

Comment: @hguser: I think the other folks here already explained it pretty well... A good title follows normal writing conventions: first letter capitalized, proper nouns capitalized (Android), etc. I should also note that you added the [tag:graph] tag when you posted on GIS, which improved the quality score slightly too.

Comment: thanks for paying this issue attention @Shog9 - i'm positive there is room to tell users about certain issues while i can see the motivation to not spell out everything. this example is one of the former IMO. there must be a happy medium. a site should not alienate the users it depends on simply for not being 'englishophiles'.

Answer (score 4):

It is the most immensely irritating crap ever. Nobody would use a compiler that just said "Error!" whenever anything went wrong. I certainly lost my inclination to post questions here. An *automatic* filter needs to justify its response.

Comment: Considering how many low-effort bad posts do get through I'd say this filter is pretty useless. But hey

Comment: If you tell people exactly what's wrong with a low-quality post, they'll do the minimum required to get it to be accepted. There are general guidelines posted in the sidebar. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121049/1288

Comment: @BilltheLizard: The alternative is that people who write posts that happen to trigger it by accident simply don't come back.

Comment: If they can't be bothered to formulate a good question, I'm ok with them not coming back.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think the point he's trying to make here is that the current settings on the quality filter are getting too many false positives. Based on the other answer, it seems that a bit too much weight is being put on the capitalization of the first letter of the title.

Comment: @BilltheLizard i have been here for a long time and have in put considerable effort helping people and writing clear and hopefully GOOD questions. I find your comment offensive and was offended when yesterday a question I spent a good 15 minutes formulating was rejected. Do you mean that people like me should leave and not come back?

Comment: @pstanton If you're putting in effort in your questions, then you're obviously not who I'm talking about, right?

Comment: @BilltheLizard then the filter is wrong. I hope we can agree on that.

Comment: @pstanton No, I really don't agree. Proper capitalization seems like a reasonable think for you to check without being told.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Then you are contradicting yourself. And if you were to run into the scenario I did yesterday without any prior knowledge of the cause, you would see my point I assure you. ps try not to make any more spelling mistakes or the quality filter might delete you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Then I wonder why does not stackoverflow publish a statement "People without good English skill will be not welcome here "? Now, to my question, I am not very good at English, but once I tried to post a question, I will write my question first in my text editor, and then read twice at least, and I would use the google translate or something else when I meet a problem. In one word, I have tried my best to make my post understood as many people as possible. Then I think what I suffered by the filter is not deserved.

Comment: And I am VERY appreciated when my post is reviewed and edited by someone. In fact, I will read the review very carefully to make sure a same error will never happen again.

Comment: Exactly, non-native english speakers are basically not allowed to ask questions now.