# "Post does not meet quality standards"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, quality-filter

I have a post written as below, which is rejected with "This post does not meet our quality standards". It was originally submitted with the title "handling errors in ex scripts without waiting for user input".

> I'm trying to perform a search/replace with an ex script (targeting vim's ex implementation), as so:
>
> ```
> ex -qc 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' file.txt
> ```
>
> However, when `file.txt` already contains no matching content, the script hangs; when run without `-q`, it also displays the error below:
>
> ```
> E486: Pattern not found: ^[#][[:space:]]*$
> ```
>
> How can I build this script to continue (or, better, abort and immediately exit) on failure, rather than awaiting user input?

I'm at something for a loss as to what rule this is likely to be triggering, or what I could do to improve it.

Comment: Have you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/167443?

Comment: Question looks fine to me, good length, good content, so no clue why it would be rejected. Did you tag it properly?

Comment: @Niels Yes -- tagged it `ex`, `vi` and `vim`.

Comment: @Jim I appreciate the pointer. Unfortunately, reading that, I find little there that's directly helpful in the context of the question at hand.

Comment: FYI the [quality filter was turned up a notch recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter). That said, your question certainly looks like a false positive.

Comment: Well semi-false - it's technically not exactly a programming question so more fit for http://unix.stackexchange.com/ I think. Still shouldn't be auto-rejected on SO though.

Comment: @Niels - I'd argue that as open to debate -- this is something that came up in the context of shell scripting. (`ed` and `ex` are the preferred ways to do in-place edits in scripts when one can need to support environments where the GNU extension `sed -i` is unavailable).

Comment: I agree it's debatable in this case and I wouldn't close it myself, just pointing out that the tagging might make it more sensitive to the quality filter.

Comment: Is that your question? If so, it's not formatted correctly.

Comment: @0A0D The formatting was changed by edits after I posted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making your title a proper English sentence

I've seen more posts like this on meta recently as a result of increasing the quality filter threshold, and often the title causes the problem.

So change the title to something like *"How should I handle errors in ex scripts without waiting for user input?"* and it will probably pass.

If that doesn't work alone, then try making full sentences between your code blocks instead of only partial sentences with the code expected to be read inline with the sentence.

> I'm trying to perform a search/replace with an ex script (targeting
>   vim's ex implementation).
>
> ```
> ex -qc 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' file.txt
> ```
>
> When file.txt contains no matching content, the script hangs, however
>   when I run it without `-q`, it displays the error below:
>
> ```
> E486: Pattern not found: ^[#][[:space:]]*$
> ```
>
> How can I build this script to continue (or better, abort and
>   immediately exit) on failure, rather than awaiting user input?

**Edit**

I just noticed the [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/180066/3) that Robert Harvey did to your question to remove the block quotes from your question, which results in a large part of your question being put in a code block.

If that was indeed how your question actually looked on SO, then he is correct in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180069/158605). But if that was only a transcription error when you posted on meta as you said in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180066/post-does-not-meet-quality-standards#comment545691_180069), then I stand by my answer (and you may want to roll back his edit to your question, as it gives the wrong impression) :)

Comment: Users should not blockquote their example questions here.  The blockquoting can obscure some relevant details, as my original edit already demonstrated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yeah, but this was a 18k+ SO user who probably knows better, so I figured it wasn't some newbie mistake like that. And it looks like he successfully [posted his question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16526147/302677) now with the title change :)

Answer (score 8):

I edited this OP so that your example post is not a quote, and now you can see that some of your question text is actually part of the code block.

To prevent this from happening, avoid indenting your paragraph text, if it is not actually code.  Paragraphs are delimited by using two carriage returns, not by indentation.

Your post should actually look like this:

---

I'm trying to perform a search/replace with an ex script (targeting vim's ex implementation), as so:

```
ex -qc 'g/^[#][[:space:]]*$/d|x' file.txt
```

However, when `file.txt` already contains no matching content, the script hangs; when run without `-q`, it also displays the error below:

```
    E486: Pattern not found: ^[#][[:space:]]*$
```

How can I build this script to continue (or, better, abort and immediately exit) on failure, rather than awaiting user input?

Comment: That was actually a transcription error between the original text and the meta question. Even so, it is useful advice.

Comment: If the title is a complete sentence I don't know how this wouldn't pass the filter.  Make sure you have ticks around ex, as in \`ex\` (it's not a real word).

Comment: ["ex" is a real word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ex)

Comment: @Yannis is right, I use "ex" in Scrabble all the time when I'm looking for 2-letter X words ;)

Comment: I'd try backticking that anyway.  SE's spell checker may not recognize it as a real word.