# Stack Overflow poor question quality patterns?

Tags: discussion, review, close-reasons

I made a simple web app that 'lints' SO questions. It basically points out a lot of common problems that lead to questions being closed, and potential solutions.

I think it should be linked in the comments of a question that's either on-hold or has a couple close votes. Hopefully it'll reduce the number of questions that are closed. The main goal is to be brief and targeted, as opposed to something like an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - *Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example*.

I'm looking for suggestions for some rules to add.

I mostly hover in the webdev areas of SO, so I'd be largely interested in tag-specific problems, because I don't see/understand a lot of those questions. Also, any patterns that have been noticed by Stack Overflow users; especially users who are involved in the review process.

- The most common reason I vote to close is `_______`.
- A lot of questions are missing `________`.
- Questions with the `______` tag are often closed because `______`.

Examples with Lint:

- [stacklint/17895143](http://stacklint.aboutscript.com/17895143)
- [stacklint/17894936](http://stacklint.aboutscript.com/17894936)

Example without Lint (and 6 upvotes at time of posting):

- [stacklint/17896592](http://stacklint.aboutscript.com/17896592)

Also, if you're interested in seeing the current rules in code, and suggesting technical improvements, this is [staticlint.coffee](https://github.com/brigand/StackLint/blob/master/coffee/stacklint.coffee).

(I realize this is on the borderline of StackApp, but my question is about patterns of Stack Overflow questions, which wouldn't be able to be answered elsewhere.)

Comment: Not related to your question but your app seems to be slightly wrong; you can't always "complain" that there's too much code and also state that the OP didn't try to help themselves? EDIT: Just seen your "it's difficult to do"... fair enough.

Comment: You're also not following the [CC-Wiki attribution requirements](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) as defined by SE in the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)... I like the general idea a lot though... if you can get something working it would be really good to be able to define automagically what _exactly_ might be wrong with a question.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand, I gave you an upvote, in principal, this is a an excellent idea and I take my hat off to you for your efforts to improve our site :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards you should put your comments into an answer. I think you have made good points

Comment: Well, I for one hope that question closures are not nearly this formulaic. If they *were*, we wouldn't need a lint-style tool, we would just need to [tighten up the question quality filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter) so that these questions didn't get posted in the first place.

Comment: @CodyGray yes I agree with you, but it could be altered to cater for different tags, as some language questions require code examples, some do not, they require an explanation

Comment: This is a pretty cool idea. Interested to see how it works out.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question though @Skippy; personally, I think that any single "rule" will not work as the type of questions are far too varied. I get told off for everything being to long on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806910); it's almost impossible to shorten it. I would probably increase the amount of text "allowed" but in some circumstances that would be ridiculous; for instance [this comes out okay](http://stacklint.aboutscript.com/16544867)... because it's short.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, have a recommendation on how to comply?  Would turning the title into a link satisfy the attribution?  I could change it to a single code block exceeding X characters or Y lines.

Comment: According to the legal page something along the lines of the following would be enough: small footer saying it came from SE. Question title as link back to the question; you also need to include the author though with a link back to their user-page.

Comment: @CodyGray, this will through out quite a few false positives.  That's why someone needs to look at it, and decide whether the lint is accurate enough to post.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards yes I understand, it is not a straightforward, nor easy thing to 'successfully' implement (if possible) but it sure is interesting. I also made the comment that the rules would need to very, depending on tag

Comment: I would be very interested in seeing the results of such a test, once you get this up and running.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, the attribution thing is fixed.  Thanks for pointing that out :-)  I'm rewriting part of it to allow filtering by tags more easily.  Feel free to post answers outlining what conditions there are for a **good question** in a **certain tag** (or tags).

Comment: Just a +1 for the effort. It's a pretty cool thing you've created. If it only ever servers to inspire, you've already done well.

Comment: Did you enter any part of this in the [Stack Exchange machine learning contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-machine-learning-contest/) they ran last year? If no, you might want to write the team and see if this would be of interest, because this seems in line with what they might do with some of the entries from that contest.

Comment: @BradLarson, I only spent a few hours on this before posting :-)  I hadn't heard of that, but I'd love to send a link.  I don't see any clear point-of-contact, other than the forum which likely isn't monitored.  By the way, I'm making copy-as-comment buttons, which optionally include the auto generated reasons.  Hopefully this could be integrated in SO, even just a suggestions before posting.  That's why I'm making the lint file data-source independent.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - I mean via the "contact us" links at the bottom of the pages here. They'll probably see your Meta post, but a message to the Stack Exchange team couldn't hurt.

Comment: `'i tried', 'when i', 'i am trying'` You might want to add a few more there, such as "I have tried," "I already tried," "I have so far," etc

Comment: @Doorknob, I'll add those.  I might just have 'tried', 'when i', and 'i have'.  The 'i am trying' often doesn't actually indicate effort, as in 'I am trying to make a jQuery dialog, but it isn't working' (and I've seen worse).  Btw, I sent a message, Brad.