# Title and question body are the same

Tags: feature-request, title

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283551/does-the-jdbc-have-its-own-transaction-manager-or-does-it-just-call-the-transac). The title and question body are the same. I think this is not a good practice. Is it possible to create a mechanism to force a user to give a brief description which is different from the title?

Screenshots of sample question.

[image]

Comment: You could have gone meta-meta and made your title and question the same. This is a sad lost opportunity.

Comment: I don't think the problem here is so much the *repetition*, but the fact that [excessively short questions should be caught by the quality filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174097/is-it-time-to-tighten-up-the-question-quality-filter). That would save us the trouble of having to put it on hold as "unclear", and cajole the person to editing it.

Comment: restricting number of words in "title" may be solve this problem. I used to use this process in my project.

Comment: I can't see that question, it was removed for moderation reasons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The [current Ask page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/289691) doesn't allow to post a new question having the same body as the title. It also limits the title length to be between 15 and 150 characters while the body minimal length is 30 characters.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As unlikely as it sounds, people do occasionally ask on-topic questions that are in both the title and body of the question.

This doesn't happen often enough to warrant a system change to detect it, and users will just get around it by adding extra junk characters to either the title or the body, which makes the cure  worse than the cold.