# It shouldn’t be possible to flag questions as Very Low Quality

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, low-quality-posts

The “very low quality” flag, on questions, is vague. It means “do something”, and that’s not helpful. I think it’s pretty well covered by the variety of flaggable close reasons/an actual close vote, and “other”. It’s rarely helpful when a question “needs” to be closed faster, but an edit dismisses it.

Can we get rid of it? Please?

Comment: Like those vague "should be migrated to another site" flags that make me ask "What site?"

Comment: If people vote like they should then there would be no need for the VLQ flag.

Comment: @JanDvorak This looks like off-topic questions. And maybe spam.

Comment: @dystroy shouldn't they be deleted (quick, ideally)?

Comment: yes, but "low quality" sounds wrong for them.

Comment: What as, then? [I have been told not to flag as spam if it isn't technically spam](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/dont-flag-as-spam) and it's not literally offensive either.

Comment: Martijn, who knows much better SO and meta than me, said to flag as "other".

Comment: okay then. I was still hoping for the six-flag effect

Comment: Pardon me while I go create a *whole lot* of sock puppets to up vote this.

Comment: @JanDvorak Speaking as a CS mod: if it quacks like an astroturfer and it walks like an astroturfer, it's spam, even if the spammer somehow never gets around to posting his answer. Basically, VLQ is “this post should be destroyed post-haste”, spam/offensive is “this account should be destroyed post-haste”.

Answer (score 19):

I would like the SE team to look at the metrics on the numbers of declined VLQ flags on posts. -- I *rarely* find myself marking them helpful if we keep a stricter definition of VLQ.

It should either be removed as an option, or some text should be added that makes it clear that the post needs to be gone:

> very low quality: This post is not salvageable; it should be deleted *immediately*.

Answer (score 13):

Per my observations through recent months, tightened quality filter ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176875/165773), [2](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5857/31260)) has made VLQ questions very rare birds at Stack Overflow and at Programmers.

- When "eligible" posts are as rare, having flag for these could do more harm than good. Flagging the right way is a skill that needs *practice* and flagger who had not seen *true* VLQ questions for weeks or even months, is at risk of misusing the flag, casting it wrong.

Asker has to try real hard to make a post that would both 1) look like [unsalvageable through editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/low-quality-posts/info) and 2) pass the filter with its current settings. These two "criteria" almost exclude each other.

<sub>For the sake of completeness, I think that before dropping this flag for questions it would make sense to study questions flagged VLQ at sites that may have lower settings of quality filter.</sub>