# How to handle a very bad quality question without the "Very low quality" flag?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, low-quality-posts

Today, I read a post of a very frustated man which tried to resolve a problem during a lot of hours without finding the solution. All I had was this:

> Eight hours of trying TO GET first and last character (number) FROM String Please help TO find THE solution

Also he pasted a snippet of his code. So I read it and saw that the snippet did not contain even one try to resolve the problem.

The user was a new user, and I don't want to blame him. But this kind of question start to be very frequent (I'm following the Android tag). I understand that everybody can be a bit frustrated and that you can write a badly formatted question one day. But I find it too easy to let this kind of unconstructive question to be answered by some people. I think that the OP will not make any effort in the future to write better questions as he has answers anyway.

We can select a "Very low quality" flag for an answer in the "Review" part, but not for a question. Actually, I don't really understand why.

**New feature idea (but not really a feature request as it's just a discussion about it)**

Instead of a "Very low quality" flag, we could add a flag "Need edit" or something like this. This way, if a moderator validate the flag, the post will be "not answerable" until the OP make an edit, which should be reviewed to be back to an "answerable" state.

Comment: Why can't we just close the question? The close reason tells the OP to edit the question; they edit it and the question goes back to the reopen review queue... Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have not the permission to close a question. Maybe it's because I don't have the needed reputation and here is the problem. But maybe I could help the more trusted users to identify this kind of content. I will edit my post to add these details :)

Comment: Anybody with 3k rep can cast close votes and *they do*. If you have <3k, you can just flag to close - I really don't think we need a whole new review queue and flag just for this...

Comment: I agree with you. I still do not know how to flag a post that is poorly written (I mean : a post I need to make a lot of effort to understand what is the actual problem instead of making an effort to resolve it).

Comment: Related: [Why can questions be flagged but not closed for very low quality?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554).

Comment: Just downvote, vote to close, and move on.  He didn't give two sheets, why should you?  Farg him. Fargin' iceholes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Very Low Quality (VLQ) means that a post is completely and totally unable to be saved by an edit or anything and it should be deleted immediately.  VLQ quality flags on questions are weird because the flag doesn't send them into the close review queue. If a question is currently being reviewed for closure, then the [VLQ flag option is not available for use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286972/426671)

If you come across something that needs to be closed, then flag it for closure.  VLQ flags are still available at other times including from some of the review queues, like the Help and Improvement queue.

Comment: Ok. So the solution is in the "Triage" part. So if I read a bad question (maybe a question missed in Triage), I just can't make something to tell that it's really badly formatted ?
Also : is questions in Triage are visible in the main thread ?

Comment: @mithrop If you are in Triage reviewing (which is appears you were), you will not have a VLQ option by design. If you find a terrible question, then you should be selecting Unsalvageable on the question.

Comment: I was not. I was just reading a question in the main thread of the "Android" tag in StackOverflow. I was not reviewing anything, just reading a post that was poor. I didn't know what to do to help improving and so I try to find a solution ;)

Comment: @mithrop I thought you were in review.  I've edited my answer if a question is currently in the close vote review queue, then the VLQ option is no longer available.  That's what happened in this case.  In these cases, then you should flag a question for closure. Flag > should be closed... > then select the reason why.

Comment: ok. I understand a little better. We are back on the question in another comment : "I still do not know how to flag a post that is poorly written (I mean : a post I need to make a lot of effort to understand what is the actual problem instead of making an effort to resolve it)". When I choose "should be closed...", I don't find a good reason. It's maybe "Too broad" ? Can I use this for "formatting problem" for example ?

Comment: @mithrop A question shouldn't be closed for a formatting problem, that's what edits are for. The question should fit one of the existing close reasons, if it doesn't then maybe it's not off-topic and should just be downvoted on or commented on.

Comment: ok. so comment and/or downvote. Thank you *very much* for your answer ;)

Comment: it's unlikely that asker saw it from review. If I understand correctly: [GET first and last character (number) FROM String android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31319305/839601) - "Eight hours of trying TO GET first and last character (number) FROM String Please help TO find THE solution..."