# I'm unable to post question on stackoverflow.com too many times

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I found myself in the posture giving up posting to stackoverflow.com too many times. The question meets the quality standard and I have enough point to submit a question. After about half an hour I just gave up. I think that stackoverflow.com is extremly restrictive, without exagerating.

The latest message was:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: It does not meet our quality standards.

The question was:

---

> **TITLE:**   jquery element selector reference
>
> **CONTENT:**
>   I'm having to many selectors (`like $(document)`) on a webpage and i wanna initiate them through a variable like `var doc_el
>   = $(document);` to lower the requests into jquery dom pool.
>
> The question is: **It will double the memory or it will be a
>   reference?**
>
> I'm asking because this i had a problem once, where a variable would
>   not engage as reference. I can't give an example because i don't know
>   where i've used that.
>
> **TAGS:**   [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)

Comment: try formatting the question properly and change the question title slightly

Comment: "The question meets the quality standard" but you still get " It does not meet our quality standards..." Someone is mistaken :P  The question *does* look to me to be acceptable...

Comment: Capitalize your I's. Always.

Comment: Probably not enough jQuery

Comment: And (though a personal pet peeve), what is wrong with "want to" instead of "wanna"?

Comment: @kia - possibly yes... but does the post look **that bad** to you?

Comment: "i" should be "I", "i've" should be "I've" or "I have". @Lix - FYI as well. Also "wanna" is considered low English quality. Change to "want to".

Comment: @sha - I'm not going to edit the quoted question - that's part of the meta post - it would be like making an edit to a code block :P

Comment: @Lix not asking anyone to edit, just spreading what I know that can cause the quality filter to trigger.

Comment: @sha - ah - Ok... I see so much "i" and "i've" and wanna" in posts on [so] - I hardy believe that it would trip the filter... I could be wrong though...

Comment: @Lix Apart from what said from Sha Dow Wiz Ard, see also, "I'm asking because this i had a problem once." We don't discuss of the filter implemented for the quality standards because details about it will not be disclosed.

Comment: Ok - you are both correct - but I'm sure we can agree that we've **all** seen *much* worse stuff on [so] that seemed to have passed the filters.

Comment: @Lix agreed, I just say from experience - people changed "i" to "I" and got their question posted.

Comment: @sha - I just did that and it posted it.

Comment: @Lix afaik quality filter is turned off here on Meta. :/

Comment: @sha - on the main site...

Comment: @Lix you got too much rep there - I also believe it's taken into account. :)

Comment: @Lix never had the courage to try on the main site but yes, the system might rely on the integrity of high rep members. :)

Comment: @sha - First time I tried **I did** get the quality filter message.  Capital "i"'s was the only thing I changed - then it went though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, your question does seem to comply with the quality filter.  I'm not 100% sure why you are not being allowed to post this.  It is a rather simple question but that should not matter.

You have a rather generic title - each word in the title could essentially be a tag for this question.  As was mentioned in the comments, you should try to give your post a more unique title - possibly something like :

**Caching selectors in jQuery** <sub>(seems like this might be a dupe to start with though :)</sub>

<s>As was also said in the comments - correct use of capitalization will always be welcomed but I hardly believe that that would trip the filter.  I see so much lack of capitalization on SO posts.</s>

Capitalization seems to have been the issue here - fix that and you should be able to post it. I was able to successfully post your question by simply capitalizing all the "i"'s.

Try to always use correct English wherever possible - If you slip up somewhere - the community will come along and fix it - but in the original post you should make as much effort as you can to use correct English.

Comment: I know that "i" should be uppercase in a sentence, but I haven't thought this would be my problem. I think I did this before, when I just dropped my questions for not being able to post them.

Comment: Seems that it **was** this that tripped the filter.

Comment: Again, stackoverflow.com should help in this matter. I don't think I'm the only one here that just dropped the question.

Comment: [so] is not a site to teach you how to type correct English - I disagree - it is 100% the OP's responsibility.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I meant that stackoverflow.com should post WHY your question is not accepted. Just because my native language is not english, it doesn't mean that I should not post my question to stackoverflow.com before I learn to write a perfect english.

Comment: @machineaddict: It's part of the "keeping bad stuff away from the system". If SO would tell people what's wrong, they'd fix *that* and nothing else, or worse, would find a way to circumvent it. It's a sad world we live in, but such measures are necessary.