# How does the quality filter work?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions

When one asks a simple question on this forum, the site doesn't allow the user to post it, as it detects that the question is too easy as per the Q&A and user standards.

My question is, what algorithm does Stack Exchange employ here that assesses the difficulty level of the question asked?

Being a computer engineer I am not able to even get a hint of that. Do they search for key words like "what", "simple thing" etc.?

Comment: No algorithm, just hard-working people. And your question is better suited to Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

We do not have the feature you describe. There is nothing that detects questions as "too easy". In fact, there is nothing wrong with asking "easy" questions. What's easy to one person may not be easy for another. That's the whole premise behind a collaboratively-edited Q&A site.

There is, however, something wrong with asking questions that don't make any sense, that more closely resemble "assignments" rather than questions, that show no effort of research effort on the part of the asker, that cannot be reasonably answered, and that are not correctly formatted.

To this end, we *do* have a **quality filter** in place. You can read more about it, and how to compose your question to avoid tripping it, in the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards).

Also, please see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq/) for more information on the types of questions you can and cannot ask.

If you're still having trouble asking your question on Stack Overflow, please edit your question here and include the full text of the question you're attempting to post. We will be more than happy to tell you what's wrong with it and give you some suggestions on how to improve it.

Comment: how could you detect a question, if it make no sense using some keyword filtering?

Comment: @user You can't. We don't do that either. That's what close votes are for.

Comment: sometimes I cant post a question, I only get a message that this question does not meet the standards.

Comment: Ah, there is a secret "quality" detection algorithm. Updated answer to reflect that. Top secret how it works, though. We don't want people working around it easily. We want people to actually fix their questions.