# quality standards not met

Tags: support, quality-filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I had a good question IMHO:

"I want to sign two dozen jar files using jarsigner, giving the password only once. Is this possible; if so, how?"

with two tags "jar-signing" and "applet" and a subject line "bulk-signing of jar files"

It was not accepted and I think it's a bug.

Comment: First of all, "ununderstandbly" is not a word...

Comment: OK, the typo was fixed.

Comment: Still not a word...

Comment: OK, I have removed the Wortneuschöpfung

Comment: This is not a bug.  The quality standards filter is working as designed.

Answer (score 3):

Your question seems to be too short and could be enhanced with more information about your situation.

1. Your subject could be much clearer and possibly a Question Like "How do I sign a dozen jar-files with jarsigner"
2. You could expand the question body with examples of what you tried and what you learned from the doc
3. You should add the java tag
4. Perhaps add extra information like "I would prefer a solution for the command line, but would be okay with ant/maven solution).
5. Your operating system could be a vital information for finding a solution