# Why its saying does not meet quality standard when my issue is genuine and there is no answer of it anywhere

Tags: support, stack-overflow, rejected-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Q : How can I return data and file both in jax-rs service using cxf

Its really frustrating...my question is as below...And i cld not find answer anywhere..

I have file data as byte[] .
In jax-rs service i am returning list

```
@Produces("text/json")
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {

}

class Employee {
String name;
byte[] photo; 
}
```

SO when i return list, i want lint to list employee with its photo.

How can i achieve this ?

call to getEmployee is an ajax call.

i want to list employees with its photoid.

Comment: Forget it..asking somewhere else...Don't see what's really wrong with question...First time facing such stupid issue...there are more useless questions like "return with in webservice"...

Comment: @Peter, your attempts to improve the quality of *this* question ended up accidentally changing the context of the question being caught in SO's quality filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quality standard filter analyzes formatting and spelling, not the *content* of your question.

You might start by capitalizing the `I`s (as you should in English) and go on from there.

Comment: does not work...

Comment: I see lots of uncapitalized `i`'s in questions that aren't caught by this filter, so I'm not sure that's exactly the reason. Still, it's a pet peeve of mine and I's should be capitalized.

Comment: As I said, go on from there. It's not the only thing that affects the filter.

Comment: @Jigar you're lying, or you didn't capitalize them all. I just tested it myself, I capitalized all the i's and it went through.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags Might post history be considered as well? (i.e. with your rep, can you get it to *not* go through?)

Comment: @John yup, it does *not* go through for me in its original form. There is no rep consideration in the quality filters, as a matter of principle, the team are very strict about that

Comment: I am still not getting. What is missing ? What capitalization is missing..."How Can I Return Data and File Both in JAX-RS service using CXF" also tried "How can I return Data and File both in JAX-RS service using CXF" does not work...And why i should be lying...!

Comment: @JigarShah: We're not understanding each other. What I meant was that you should replace every lowercase `i` by an uppercase `I` in the entire question body.

Comment: Wooh..Finally...In overall conversation I thought just question not body...I thought its tech discussion forum...its English test forum too...!

Comment: Yes, it is. A reasonable, even if basic, command of English is required to use our site. And things like this are even more basic than basic...