# Merge two accounts please

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I have two accounts - who do I contact to merge them. Thanks

Also, the one line question above did not meet the quality standards - how do I do that please?

Thanks again

Comment: Include your account links. And keep information on both account same. Flag one of your question from one account. And give custom message notifying links old both accounts.

Comment: Related - [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have merged your accounts and return to using the site, please be aware that -

A one line question most probably did not meet the quality standards... Questions should 
contain enough information so that we can understand what exactly is wrong with the code.  That brings me to my next point - including code in your questions is always a good idea (where applicable).

The algorithms that detect when a question is of low quality is highly secret otherwise people would be able to circumvent the limitations enforced by the quality filter.  Consider beefing up your questions with relevant information that'll help the community help you...