# Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

When trying to submit a question, I'm receiving the following message:

> Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

Where should I write my context and how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Comment: @UristMcBobby No, it's not.

Comment: @balpha: and now I want to vote for the 'let me retract a moderator flag' feature suggestion *again*..

Comment: Don't understand why this question got downvoted so hard. This user is obviously new and has English as a second language. Mentions like "quality standards" or "posting format" won't jump to such a user's attention during the first visits. The FAQ could really benefit from an illustrative example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You get that message when you're trying to post just a bunch of code without any explanation of what you're trying to accomplish, what problems you're running into, what approaches you have already tried, etc.

If you want people to help you, you have to be clear about such things. Try to post as little code as possible while still posting enough to clarify the issue, and also describe your problem clearly. A huge block of code with an additional "This doesn't work" makes it extremely hard for people to be of any assistance.

Bottom line: You should help people to help you, as much as you can.

Comment: thnx a lot but still what if i cant cut short my code??

Comment: @user1458650 The main point is not *shortening your code*, but explaining, in normal language, what the problem is. Except for a bunch of code, the only text in the question you tried to submit was "hi i am new to andoid plz help". How are people supposed to know *what to help you with?* In addition, when asking people to help you, you should have the courtesy to write reasonable text and not a bunch of txtspeek.

Comment: thnx i was not getting where i could write the context ..
now i get it