# Error description on ask page - unable to decipher

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, error-message

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I was about to ask a question on a SE site. I entered meaningful title, more than 80 char's in body and added 2 tags. I got following error on submitting

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

This error message should be more descriptive as to what was not meeting quality standards?

I changed the title and gave little more description and was able to successfully post it.

Comment: The error message is vague on purpose, so you actually improve the post all you can instead of just fixing the minimum. There have been false positives though. Any chance you have a copy of the question?

Comment: I tried it again, and the low-quality area was the title so, hmm, I see this error message is generic and may also apply to the main body as well in some other cases.

Comment: Nobody but the devs knows *exactly* how the filter works. What was the title?

Comment: The title was `Who are the Sahaba?`  on Islam.SE.