# I keep getting "It does not meet our quality standards"

Tags: support, quality-filter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

What is wrong with my question?

This is my question:

> currently i am using **testng** 6.8 with maven but when run the test
>   through **intellij** plugin it use old version of tesng.
>
> how can i make intellij(version 11.1.4) work with TestNG 6.8 ?
>
> i know that intellij-idea will release new version of intellij-idea
>   intellij  in December, will this  version contain new TestNG plugin ?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to know what's going to happen in the future? You're asking people to _guess_. How can that be an answerable question?

Comment: i understand, i remove the question about the future and still get "It does not meet our quality standards."

Answer (score 6):

A few observations regarding the question you posted:

- Sentences should begin with a capital letter
- "I" should be capitalized, even in the middle of a sentence
- Only one question mark is necessary
- There's **no need** to bold things unless they really need to stand out

With all due respect to any other languages that may have different standards, these are the acceptable practices in English.

Also note that if your title is nearly the same as the body of your question, it's likely that you need to add more information to the body.

Comment: @user1835346: generally speaking: activate your spell checker, there were a few easily avoidable typos in [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452618/how-to-update-intellij-testng-plugin-to-testng-version-6-8).