# What's wrong with my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

I wanted to post this question on Stack OverFlow.

> I need to put some `production` specific behavior in `mule-config`. Is there a way to get environment info in mule?
>
> Thanks

but it says

**Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
It does not meet our quality standards.**

without saying what quality standards it doesn't meet.

**EDIT:**

I edited the question by removing unnecessary tick and thanks as suggested (I'm not sure what's the problem in saying thanks though). I don't have any more relevant details about the question. Code sample doesn't make any sense here. I still cannot submit it.

And a possible duplicate question link doesn't help me in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Three things come to mind:

1. Abuse of backticks to format non-code like code. This hurts readability rather than helps it.
2. You have literally one line of value, you need more meat and potatoes. We're going to starve!
3. Your question ends with the unnecessary "Thanks"

I'll bet if you added more to your question, including what you have tried and perhaps a snippet of your mule-config, and got rid of the excess backticks and "Thanks", your question will be accepted.

Comment: Please see my edit in question. I don't have other relevant information for question

Comment: You obviously have a configuration file of some sort you could add. If you have no other information then unfortunately your question is not appropriate for our network.