# Why does my question supposedly not meet the quality standards?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-filter

I'm trying to post the following question and get:

> This post does not meet our quality standards.

Why?

This is the question:

> I'm writing an iphone application that sends email, sms and make phone calls, exiting i know :)
>
> since i can't test from the simulator that any of the code i wrote actually work, i'd like to deploy the application on my iphone without a developer license.
>
> i'm looking for dummies tutorial (step 1...step 2...), can anyone refer me to one
>
> thanks

The title is:

> in need for good tutorial on deploying ad-hoc

and the tags are: [ad-hoc-distribution](/questions/tagged/ad-hoc-distribution) and [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

Comment: See: [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards). I would add that your question looks like a ["shopping question"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: obviously i searched the internet and didn't find something easy to follow, as well as looked first at other Q&A and didn't find an answer so when posting mine how can i know what should i improve in order for the question to post

Comment: @LiblibFbi, I searched google for "how to deploy app to iphone without developer liscence" and two of the top results were stackoverflow posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494398/install-ios-apps-on-device-without-developer-program-ios-5-1 -- naturally, you can only do this with a jailbroken device.

Comment: @BenLee thanks for your answer,  i don't have a jailbroken device,   from what i read the whole idea of ad-hok is to be able to test your application prior to loading it to the store or being able to download it not through the store (like vlc player for example), is there a way i can do that? if not do you have a recommendation on jailbrake cause from my understanding since hakulus retired there is no good option out there

Comment: @LiblibFbi, I'm not an iPhone developer, and I can't help you with those questions. I'm just telling you what I found on google.

Answer (score 15):

Asking for tutorials is not constructive for the site; any answers would be equally valid.

You should Google for some tutorials, take a stab at some code, and if you get stuck, come back with what you have tried and what doesn't work