# Why is this question rejected?

Tags: support

My question is rejected "does not meet our quality standards" why?

> Hi,
>
> Is there a way to create a model from a form in django(1.5)? Like
>   when creating forms from models ?
>
> Thanks

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards?rq=1

Comment: Yes[.](http://yourquestionisjustayesnoquestion.)

Comment: @wont what yes ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a low quality question.

I see no research effort, no display of what you have tried. No code.

It is also unclear and not well phrased - what does "Like when creating forms from models ?" mean? Why not give an *example*?

Comment: should i provide a link to the django documentation ? or do you think an example of an inexisting code and a few google search will suffice ?

Comment: @maazza - How would a link to documentation make the question any clearer? You need to show, in your question, what you tried. Explain what is not working for you - show code if you have it.

Comment: did you read the question ? if not you should

Comment: @maazza - Yes. I read the question. Did you read my answer? If not you should. You have made no effort to solve the problem on your own - the question shows that. If you had made an effort, you would have asked a different question.

Comment: thanks a lot and sorry to waste your time