# "This post does not meet our quality standards" idea: linking to essays

Tags: discussion, feature-request, quality-filter

http://pastebin.com/DLhNDNSN

I'm unable to post that on stackoverflow without getting a "*This post does not meet our quality standards*" and I don't know why. I understand the [exact algorithm details aren't being disclosed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92075/186308). But I do think stackoverflow could be more helpful than it is being.

Another post I was unable to make [will getcwd() and exec('pwd') always match?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16109799/569976) . The original title I had was "*php: getcwd vs. exec('pwd')*" and I got the same "*This post does not meet our quality standards*" message. But in that case I at least understand why. stackoverflow probably saw the "vs." and thought I was [going shopping](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) even though I wasn't. Not that a new user would have known that.

Seems to me that the least that could be done when the "*This post does not meet our quality standards*" message is displayed is that an essay could be linked to or something.

edit: Here's an example of what I mean by an essay:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: It's worth noting that the first post could potentially be considered off topic. There's also a lot of punctuation in that message, and what would probably show up as "poorly formatted code," so I'm not surprised that hit the filter. I've seen that posts which have gargantuan code blocks are typically downvoted, and I wouldn't be surprised if the heuristic used that metric too.

Comment: Prefixing a subject with "php:" may set it off as well. It doesn't like tags in the title, in many cases

Comment: @animuson: What does he mean by "linking to essays?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Maybe ask the OP? :P

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: Eh, he's not here.  Just another drive-by post.  Ah, crap, you're right; it's off-topic anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm pretty sure they will be back. Also, they may be referring to documents like Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), though I'm not too sure.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi: Alright.  Closing as dup.

Comment: A sample essay: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ I linked to it in the OP. Ironically, I also linked to the post that this post is marked as a duplicate of...  oh well.