# This post does not meet our quality standards

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, question-quality, quality-filter

I am trying to post on stackoverflow site, but keep getting "This post does not meet our quality standards."
Yes I am new.  What am I doing wrong?

> > I am starting learn Ruby, need some help with the include? method.
>
> The below code works just fine:
>
> ```
> x = 'ab.c'
> if x.include? "." 
>   puts 'hello'
> else
>   puts 'no'
> end
> ```
>
> But when I code it this way:
>
> ```
> x = 'ab.c'
> y = 'xyz'
> if x.include? "." || y.include? "."
>   puts 'hello'
> else
>   puts 'no'
> end
> ```
>
> If gives me error when I run it:
>
> ```
> test.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' o
> r '\n'
> if x.include? "." || y.include? "."
>                                  ^
> test.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting end-of-input
> ```
>
> Is this because the include? method cannot have handle logic operator?
>
> Thanks

Comment: Well this is an interesting example. I'm going to link you [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards?rq=1), but I'm not sure that's going to be very helpful for you. Try removing the "thanks"? I mean, I'd upvote this as is, but still... I hope we're still allowed to thank people.

Comment: I'm guessing the lower-case letter following a question mark, twice, is a negative indicator. A false positive in this case, as it happens.

Comment: Putting "include?" as `include?` might help.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm...

You *should* be getting this error:

[image: These words are not allowed in titles: 'help with']

(I'm assuming the first line you quoted *was* your title; if you used a different title, please include that too)

The title you've written is not very descriptive of your question. If possible, try to *summarize your question* when writing the title, including as much *specific* information as you can manage while keeping it brief. I would recommend something like the following:

> #### What causes "unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'" when trying to use a second include? condition?

If you're *not* seeing the error message I posted above, please clarify the title and tags you're using when trying to post, and I'll dig into this further.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
Changed the lower case to capitalize in my title and voila, it went through.
I was just trying to keep it as close to the ruby syntax as possible

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, your title *was* different...