# Should question length have a greater impact on the low quality filter to help stop this?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366773/multicore-architectures) was, when posted:

> Please justify your answer. As the description on the title, you will know the question.

That's it.

If it isn't currently, shouldn't question length be more of a factor in determining "low quality" questions?

Comment: P.S. this even hit the review queue because such a significant percentage was edited: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2051846

Comment: Perhaps there should be a minimum of 89 characters.

Comment: I'm not so sure that minimum lengths work that well @Knights, though I agree 89 would have been good in this case :-). There are plenty of good arguments out there against minimum lengths, which is why it's so low. I'm just asking if it should have a greater weight, possibly only in certain circumstances (no idea what the actual algorithm is). I don't understand, at all, how this got through...

Comment: Ah, I was being slightly sarcastic :P Still, point taken. I'm also curious how this did, and something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177330/this-post-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) didn't.